# Get value from checkbox inside iterator, in struts2

Tags: jsp, checkbox, struts2, iterator

I have a checkbox inside an iterator, in a JSP page. Whatever I tried, the attribute value of the checkbox tag stay with the 'true' value, even when the value of the field value is the one I want. But I can't get back it. I only get 'true'.

```jsp
 <s:iterator
    id="pieceJointe"
    value="listePiecesJointesTrouvees">
    <tr height="30">
        <td>
            <s:property value="codeDemande" />
        </td>
        <td
            headers="actions"
            class="center">         
            <s:checkbox 
            value="%{chemin}"
            fieldvalue="%{chemin}"                      
            name="checkbox" /> 
        </td>           
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

The variable `chemin` getting back with fieldset attribute is the one I want. I can see it with the Web Inspector but I can't take it in the code. I only get back the value of 'value' variable which is desperately "true" value.

Comment: you value is the same as fieldvalue, the reason of using the same value for both fields?

Comment: Show your action; meanwhile, read http://stackoverflow.com/a/35064012/1654265 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/21827853/1654265 to get some tips on how the checkbox thing works

Answer (score 0):

When using `iterator` tag to populate a page with input elements like checkbox you can use `value` attribute to preselect the state of checkbox. The `fieldValue` is different it's used to set the actual value of the generated HTML checkbox, but [`s:checkbox` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/checkbox-tag.html) is a composite tag, along with HTML checkbox tag it also generates a hidden field and set the field value into it. So you don't have to use `value` and `fieldValue` with the value from the list.

Again, using `iterator` tag with the list and a requirement to submit those values. You should use indexed property names. This indexed names are used as parameter's names in the request, and allows to be populated via [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) to the list property of the action class.

```
<s:iterator
    id="pieceJointe"
    value="listePiecesJointesTrouvees" status="status">
    <tr height="30">
        <td>
            <s:property value="codeDemande" />
        </td>
        <td
            headers="actions"
            class="center">         
            <s:checkbox 
            value="%{chemin}"
            name="listePiecesJointesTrouvees[%{#status.index}].chemin" /> 
        </td>           
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

---

Make sure you use default stack of interceptors which include [`checkbox` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/checkbox-interceptor.html). This interceptor is required to populate *unchecked* values.