# AngularJS Not able to pass model data to server model appears as empty string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to send some simple data to the server.  I take the originally received server data used to create dynamic forms, quickly clean up unnecessary keys using delete formData['not_needed'], and then I wanted to add the model that has been created before posting to the server, but when I check the data objects model key that I'm trying to add it is always an empty string.  I can either send one or the other, but can't seem to add one object to another as a key-value pair.

```
// Abridged version
var formData = $scope.responseData; // original server data to build forms
delete formData['config_data']; // remove unnecessary keys

formData.model = $scope.formModel; // add model key

$http.post('/restful/api', formData).then(function(success) {...}, function(error) {...});
```

The output of passed data from the server looks like:

```
{ id: "1", type: "type_of_form", name: "name_of_package", model: "" } // model always empty
```

Is this an issue using $scope?

**UPDATE**

Even when I hardcode the outgoing keys:

```
var packageData = {
    "packageid": $scope.formData.id, // makes it to server
    "desc": $scope.formData.desc, // also makes it to server
    "data": $scope.formModel // is just an empty string
}
```

But formModel filled from some dumby form data when logged to console and printed out to the screen using a filter { formModel | json } looks like:

```
formModel = {
  "document_date": "1234",
  "first_name0": "1",
  "first_name1": "2",
  "first_name2": "3",
  "first_name3": "4"
}
```

Comment: if you do `console.debug($scope.formModel)` and `console.debug(formData)` just before calling `$http.post(...)` what do you get in the console?

Comment: two objects with all their properties

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're running into the by-now famous "AngularJS cannot form-URL-encode data it POSTs by default" pitfall; if so, you'll need to do this before you try and post:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  // Intercept POST requests, convert to standard form encoding
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.unshift(function (data, headersGetter) {
    var key, result = [];
    for (key in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]));
      }
    }
    return result.join("&");
  });
}]);
```

via [How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)