# Flask with Angular: POST form is empty

Tags: python, ajax, angularjs, python-3.x, flask

I'm sending data via AngularJS POST request:

```
$http.post('/process', { 'uid': uid, 'action': action }).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

And trying to get sended values in Flask

```
@app.route('/process', methods = ['POST'])
def process():
    return json.dumps({ 'data': request.form.get('uid', 'EMPTY') })
```

And Flask returns back {"data": "EMPTY"} response. `request.form` is empty. I've tried to get data from `request.data`, but it's in strange format there.

I'm learning Python and Flask so I want to do this work with native library, without any other packages right now.

Comment: why you aren't using request.args?

Comment: @taskiner cause they are for GET requests

Answer (score 5):

`get_json()` method helps me

```
@app.route('/process', methods = ['POST'])
def process():
    return json.dumps({ 'data': request.get_json().get('uid') })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data via `request.form`, you need to have angular send it differently.  See this question for details: [How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Content-Type is application/json

Here's a tutorial series on using Flask and AngularJS together - http://tutsbucket.com/tutorials/building-a-blog-using-flask-and-angularjs-part-1/

Hope you'll find it useful.