# Reading content of $http in PHP

Tags: php, json, angularjs

I'm sending data to the server as follow:

```
$scope.saveCaption = function(user_id) {
  var target = document.getElementById('toRender');
      html2canvas(target, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
    $http({
      url: "/production/save.php?user_id="+user_id,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      data: {
        //image: canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), // commented out for testing only
        news: 'test'
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('success');
      $scope.data = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('failed');
      $scope.status = status;
    });
  }});
}
```

And trying to read it with PHP - `save.php`:

```
$data = $_POST['news'];
echo "data is $data"; die;
```

The problem is that `$_POST['news']` is always blank?

This is the data sent:

```
{"news":"test"}
```

Notice it's JSON, yet I specifically tried to change the content type:

```
'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

So how can I send normal data as opposed to JSON? Or, how can I get the php to read the JSON properly, I tried `$data = json_decode($_POST['news'])` but that gives blank too

Comment: maybe decode the entire response first? before getting the array element.

Comment: The $http service will not form urlencode your data out of the box.  See:
see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload

Comment: Alternatively, use the `php://input` stream and `json_decode` its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to form encode the parameters in data:

```
$scope.saveCaption = function(user_id) {
  var target = document.getElementById('toRender');
      html2canvas(target, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
    $http({
      url: "/production/save.php?user_id="+user_id,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      data: 'news=test', // form encoded
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('success');
      $scope.data = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('failed');
      $scope.status = status;
    });
  }});
}
```