# having hard time in working with $http.post

Tags: angularjs, django, tastypie

I'm working on an app whose back-end is django based, data is available through tastypie APIs and front is based on angularJS.

I am doing a POST request

```
$http.post('/manager/api/std/attendence/',dataObj)
         .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Attendence Posted");
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert( "failure message: " + status);
            });
```

but i am receiving a 401(unauthorized) error so i checked network panel in browser to view the requests being made and i was surprised as

first a **GET** request is made to the url specified in post and then the **POST** request is made but the url changes to page url.

this app doesn't require authentication(login) 
so, can any one help in figuring out why this post request is not working.

Comment: Why are you specifying method:'POST' when you are using $http.post

Comment: yes, i saw that and i've updated the question.

Comment: take a look at [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

Comment: How are you triggering this call? Any button in form or something else?

Comment: I think you are missing the csrf token