# Get json data from angularjs http post request thanks to servlet

Tags: json, angularjs, jakarta-ee, servlets, post

I try to send data in JSON format from angularJS client thanks to post http request and get it thanks to j2ee servlet. But I meet a mistake. My complete data can be access thanks to getParameterNames method in my servlet and I can't get it in other way.

I don't understand why my data is the Key and not a value.

**AngularJS Client**

```
setParametersForTools : function (toolName, data) {
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data) // I try with json and stringify json
    var promise = 
    $http({
        url: configuration.root_url_api+"SetParametersServlet?tool="+toolName,
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })          
    .then(function (response){
        console.log(response);
    }, function (error){
        console.log(error);
    })
    return promise;
}
```

**Servlet**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String toolname = request.getParameter("tool"); //toolname is correct

    String json = request.getParameter("data");  // return null...

    Enumeration<String> paramsName = request.getParameterNames();
    for (;paramsName.hasMoreElements();) {
        String paramName=paramsName.nextElement();
        System.out.println("param:"+paramName);
    }
}
```

**Servlet log**

```
//For Parameter names
param:tool
param:{ my correct data in json format}
```

Maybe I don't send data correctly but after many searches I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: change data: data, with data: jsonData, in your ajax

Answer (score 0):

Please make the following changes in your code.

```
setParametersForTools : function (toolName, data) {
    $http.post(configuration.root_url_api+"SetParametersServlet?tool="+toolName, data)          
         .then(function (response){
               console.log(response);
          }, function (error){
               console.log(error);
     });
 }
```

Comment: First, to resolve CORS problem, I must insert `{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}`. Then, I already test this, the problem persists.
I really don't understand why data is present as parameter name and not value..

Comment: Can i have look at data what does it contain ?

Comment: Yes, it's : `{"particularProperties":[{"PROP_A":[{"libelle":"a","value":50,"key":"A"},{"libelle":"b"
,"value":50,"key":"B"},{"libelle":"c","value":50,"key":"C"},{"libelle":"d","value":50
,"key":"D"}]}],"generalProperties":[{"PROP_B":[{"libelle":"e","value":65,"key":"E"},{"libelle":"f","value":5,"key"
:"F"},{"libelle":"g'","value":10,"key":"G"},{"libelle":"h","value":20,"key":"H"}]}]}`
I don't change the syntax but change data for confidentiality ;)

Comment: mh, sorry but I'm new in java and I can't print it. It's memory address.. ^^ How do this ?

Comment: @mukesh-kamboj Can you help him for java part

Comment: The problem is fixed thanks to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30582142/3629127). I'll post the good answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use json I'd suggest to implement JAX-RS service instead of Servlet, it will be much easier, especially if you will later use some more complex json.

Pseudo code for service (you will need to add jax-rs configuration to web.xml also):

```
@Path("/myPath")
public class MyService {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public OutputData setParameters(InputData data, @QueryParam("tool") String tool) {

        System.out.println("Input data: " + data);
        System.out.println("Tool name: " + tool);
        ...
        return outputData;
    }
}
```

where inputData and outputData are Java objects representing json.

Comment: I'm not choice. I must do this with servlet. But thank you

Comment: @Kael In that case check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload) it may provide you with some hints/solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good answer with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30582142/3629127).

**$httpParamSerializer** method fixes the problem