# Angular Ajax call being sent as request payload but not formdata after fixing

Tags: angularjs

Ok, I've tried looking at this [How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

However, I still can't seem to send my request properly.  Here are the details.

```
$scope.myData = {a: 123, b: 456};
$http({
        url: 'myfile',
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.myData),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
})
```

This keeps being sent as request payload.  Any ideas?

When I use  `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` The formdata is used however it is not parsed properly and the whole json is just one string when I look in the Chrome console.

Comment: You are still using the `application/json` content type

Answer (score 0):

$http provides an option : **params**.

Use **params:** instead of **data:**

```
 $http({
        url: 'myfile',
        method: "POST",
        params: JSON.stringify($scope.myData),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
})
```