# Handling AngularJS array in PHPMailer

Tags: angularjs, phpmailer

I am building up an application using AngularJS and PHPMailer. I need to pass an array from my Angular application to PHPMailer and then retrieve the array in PHPMailer and mail the data to the client.

```
$scope.data = {};
var link = 'http://uvw.com/mail.php';
          $http.post(link, {order:$scope.listItems}).then(function (res){
                    $scope.response = res.data;
                    console.log($scope.response);
          });
```

Here, $scope.listItems is an array which consists of head fields like customer name, customer email, customer phone etc and lots of data under each head. So it boils down to like $scope.listItems.customerName, $scope.listItems.customerPhone etc. I retrieve the data in Angular very easily using angular forEach.

i have been successful in passing the data to PHPMailer, but i have got no idea of how to retrieve the data in PHPMailer and mail it forward.

**UPDATE**

PHPMailer Code

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    
    }


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        
            {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($postdata)) {
        $request = json_decode($postdata);
        foreach ($order as $value) {
            $body=$order;
        }
        require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();               
        $mail->Host = "localhost"; 
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
        $mail->Username = "support@uvw.com"; 
        $mail->Password = "support@123";
        $mail->From = "support@uvw.com";
        $mail->FromName = "uvw";
        $mail->AddAddress("orders@uvw.com", "Orders");
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);                         
        $mail->Subject = "New Customer";
        $mail->Body    = $body;
        $mail->AltBody = "Alternate Body";
        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            exit;
        }
        echo "Message has been sent";
    }

    else {
        echo "Could not Mail";
    }
```

**$scope.listItems datastructue**

```
$scope.listItems.customerName,
$scope.listItems.customerEmail,
$scope.listItems.customerPhone,
$scope.listItems.customerAddress
```

Comment: I think you should show the PHP source code and $scope.listItems data structure

Comment: Please check update!

Answer (score 2):

## [Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zzecCg?p=preview)

The demo will allow you to test the php script using a real email server.

### Changes

- You had a `foreach` loop that was intended to add the your `$body` variable, but instead it was overwriting the variable during each loop cycle. To add to a php variable use `.=` instead of `=`.
- I like to access my php data using `$_POST`.

To access your php data using `$_POST` you will need to change your Angular Javascript to use `transformRequest` (similar to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14868725/5357459)) like this:

### Javascript

```
$http({
    method: "post",
    url: 'http://wordpress.adriancarriger.com/stack-overflow-example-33591804/',
    timeout: 20001,
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    },
    data: $scope.listItems,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}).then(function(res) {
    $scope.test.response = res.data;
    console.log(res);
});
```

### New PHP

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require $root.'/vendor/autoload.php'; // I'm using composer (optional => you can remove this if you're not using composer)

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    exit(0);
}
$list_items = $_POST;
$test_email = $list_items['testEmail'];
unset($list_items['testEmail']);
if (isset($list_items)) {
    foreach ($list_items as $key => $item) {
        $body .= '<br>'.$key.': '.$item;
    }
    //require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php"); // you can uncomment this line if you're not using composer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();               
    $mail->Host = "<host on server>"; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->Username = "so-examples@adriancarriger.com"; 
    $mail->Password = "<password on server>";
    $mail->From = "so-examples@adriancarriger.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Adrian Carriger";
    $mail->AddAddress($test_email, "Test Email");
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                         
    $mail->Subject = "New Customer";
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = "Alternate Body";
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
else {
    echo "Could not Mail";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
$request = json_decode($postdata);
foreach ($order as $value) {
    $body=$order;
}
```

That will overwrite the contents of $body every time. You need to append to it:

```
$body = '';
$request = json_decode($postdata);
foreach ($order as $value) {
    $body .= $order . "\n";
}
```