# AngularJS - Any way for $http.post to send ByteArray?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I have a byte array with some data in it. Now I want it to send the array in a RAW/Binary format to my embedded webserver:

```
var array = new Uint8Array(317);
... inserting data into array ... 

$http.post('http://api/write_file', array)          
        .then(function(response) {
            //Success
        },function(response) {
            //Fail..
    });
```

Problem is that AngularJS by default sends the array as JSON - anyway to change this? I just want it to be transmitted raw!

**EDIT:**

I've tried to overwrite the transformRespons:

```
    $http({
      url: 'http://api/write_file',
      method: 'POST',
      transformResponse: function(value) {
        return value; //Just return the value, without transform.. 
      },
      data: array
    }).then(function(response) {
             //Success
    },function(response) {
             //Fail
    });
```

But no luck? it sends exactly the same JSON as before.

Comment: I usually use FormData to send binary information.  Then just [send the form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

Comment: Under the header 'Overriding the Default Transformations Per Request' on this page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http it looks like you can override the default 'transformResponse' property.