# Express js post method reads encoded data wrongly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have my angularjs code which tries to send a post request as follows

```
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:3300/addInventoryItem',
  headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data: { 
    item_name : item.itemName
  }
};

$http(req).then(function(response){...});
```

I have my nodejs express code to have this

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/addInventoryItem", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

I always get the request in my node as

```
{ '{"item_name":"sweetB"}': '' }
```

Why is the `req.body` have the key as the entire form data as key? How can I solve this?

**EDIT**
I am using express with body-parser module

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you already added middleware to parse `x-www-form-urlencoded` request bodies (https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)?

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean that another key-value is added to your data object? Because I don't see 'item_price' in the data that your are sending.

Comment: On second look I don't think angular will urlencode the data for you, but there is a service you can use for that, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30582142/3385516

Comment: @mzulch I am using body-parser already. Still it makes the error.

Comment: @Loolooii As you see the res.body has a key value pair with the key being the entire form encoded data.

Comment: @mzulch Your second look is correct. If you can make that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Why don't you use application/json as Content-Type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending data in encoded format with request headers as json.

```
var data = $.param({
            json: JSON.stringify({
                item_name : item.itemName
            })
        });
```

Comment: I have used $httpParamSerializer to do the same task and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @mzulch in comments, you're looking for a [body parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser), so that Express would parse the request body for you.

```
var app = express();
//...
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// parse urlencoded request body
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb'}));
```

Then, in controller, you'll have an object:

```
app.post("/addInventoryItem", function(req, res) {
    // req.body is an object: {"item_name":"sweetB","item_price":10} 
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: I am using body-parser module in the nodejs code already. But then my response contains res.body which has a key value pair with the key being the entire form encoded data.