# Unable to post request using $http.post

Tags: angularjs

I just want to know whether this is the right way to post request:

```
$http.post(urlBase+'productattributecreate?'
    +"&products_id"="1"
    +"&attributes_id"=tab.attributeId
    +"&attributes_values_id"=tab.attributeValueId
    +"&regularPrice"=tab.regularPrice
    +"&salesPrice"=tab.salePrice
    +"&purchasePrice"=tab.purchasePrice
    +"&stockStatus"=tab.stockStatus
    +"&sttockQuantity"=tab.stockQuantity
    +"&minquantitySales"=tab.minQuantitySales
    +"&maxQuantitySales"=tab.maxQuantitySales
    +"&productImage"="")
```

Comment: i am using @Pathvariable in server side code for all variables

Comment: good lord, reformat that post

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload#11443066)

Comment: Consider creating a service for your server trips. It'll allow for cleaner and more maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

I think a more correct way would be:

`$http.post('../productattributecreate', uploadData)`

Where `uploadData` is an object containing all you the data:

```
var uploadData = {
    products_id = '1',
    attributes_id = tab.attributeId,
    attributes_values_id = tab.attributeValueId,
    regularPrice = tab.regularPrice,
    salesPrice = tab.salePrice,
    purchasePrice = tab.purchasePrice,
    stockStatus = tab.stockStatus,
    sttockQuantity = tab.stockQuantity,
    minquantitySales = tab.minQuantitySales,
    maxQuantitySales = tab.maxQuantitySales,
    productImage = ''
};
```

Also... It would be better if you had clarified your question with more information.

Comment: but i want all variables separately not in object format.

Comment: Take a look at @RamblinRose 's post. It may be exactly what you need.