# pass JS Objects in URL

Tags: javascript

I have already searched from this question in SO. But none of the answers worked for me, so I am posting this once more in the hope to find an answer that works for me.

Is there a way to pass JS/JSON objects through URL? Suppose I have a JS Object like so:

```
var jObj = {"color":"red","shape":"square"}
```

Now suppose I want to pass it to a URL like so:

```
window.open("/process/jObj"); //here I want the var defined above to be passed
```

I tried various options like `JSON.stringfy`, `encodeURIComponent`, `escape`..but I am not able to pass it around. Any idea how this can be achieved in pure JS?

I would like to pass it so that in the next page (process.php) such that there I can get the values of jObj and use it for further processing. Basically I am looking for an option where I can pass the object to the effect of `?color=red&shape=square` without having to squash and reformat the object too much

Comment: can you show what should be  your expectation?

Comment: What doesn't work? Does some characters disappear, or can't you fetch it again?

Comment: [querystring encoding of a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: From the child, try `opener.jObj`

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [serialization](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-json-serialization/).

Comment: have updated the question with what my expectation is. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one thing you can do

```
var jObj = {"color":"red","shape":"square"}
var urlParam = []

for (var i in jObj){
   urlParam.push(encodeURI(i) + "=" + encodeURI(jObj[i]));
}

window.open("/process/?" + urlParam.join("&"));
```

this should produce your result

Comment: You should use `encodeURI(i)` as well, since you don't know if the array keys will be URL-safe.