# How can I build a querystring from an object?

Tags: javascript, query-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [querystring encoding of a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object)

I'm trying to make a request to a website and embed the result as an `iframe` in the page using javascript. I need to pass a number of parameters in the request as querystring variables and I'd like to be able to specify the parameters as an object, passing them to a function to produce a querystring so they are easy to read, maintain and manipulate.

How can I construct the querystring of a URL from a JSON object with simple values? I would expect this example:

```
{
    h:300,
    w:300,
    skip:500,
    count:50
}
```

to produce the following querystring:

```
h=300&w=300&skip=500&count=50
```

Are there any existing library functions to do this, or is the best thing to loop over the properties myself?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, `.serialize()` works pretty well.

Comment: It's close to being a duplicate. I'd suggest the difference is that I'm willing to use any libraries where the related question is not.

Comment: His adversity to using the answers doesn't make them any less valid for you. Check out his answers and you have yours. oleq's answer is the second answer there.

Comment: Right you are - I didn't go beyond the accepted answer on my first read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has a built-in method for this: [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use jQuery's param(). Here is the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

You would pass your object like so:

var myObj = {
    h:300,
    w:300,
    skip:500,
    count:50
}

console.log('=>', $.param(myObj) );  // prints => h=300&w=300&skip=500&count=50