# how to pass param object to d3.json?

Tags: php, d3.js

My existing extJS code passes readData.php a param object

```
params: {
            start: 0,
            limit: 1000,
            proc_nm: 'sel_bkng_srch',
            srchStrng: '',
            parms: [[dnStrng,1],[mtStrng,1],[dtFromStrng,1],[dtToStrng,1]],
            connId: 'AW'
        }
```

so it can call a stored procedure which I want to share with d3. After lots of attempts, latest is:

```
d3.json("php/readData.php")
        .header("params", "params: {start: 0,limit: 1000,proc_nm: 'sel_bkng_srch',srchStrng: '',parms: [1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1]],connId: 'AW'}")
        .get(function(error, data) {
            console.log('readData: ', error) ;                
        });
```

I do not have the syntax correct to pass the object with d3.json. Everything else is functional I think - php gets called, returns an empty success object (php code needs looking at here) which is picked up back in d3. tia.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970578/how-do-i-post-parameter-on-d3-json) may help.

Comment: well I had looked at this one and could not get it to work either :-( ... will revisit it. I am using Firefox Firebug console to monitor requests etc, and from my ExtJS call I see a tab named Parameters with all the params. I have yet to successfully get any visible parms from my attempts at using D3,json etc. I can always resort to loading data with extJS and processing with D3, but I would like to work out how to get D3 to do the load as well.