# D3v5 and Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, d3.js, django-rest-framework

I'm having some trouble getting the following AJAX call to work.  I'm using D3 version 5 to make the following POST request to a Django REST Framework (DRF) ModelViewSet (version 3.x) view.  DRF provides the list of tasks under the path `/gander/tasks/` and allows one to create a new one by POST'ing to the same path.  I believe I'm retrieving the CSRF token correctly but I'm not sure I'm formulating the POST properly.

```
d3.json("/gander/tasks/?format=json",
 {method:"POST",
  headers:{
   "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
   "X-CSRFToken" : Cookies.get('csrftoken') },
  body:JSON.stringify({
   "parent": null,
   "name"  : "",
   "time"  : null}),
 })
 .then(json => {console.log(json);})
 .catch(error => {console.log(error);});
```

I've gone through the Django A.J.A.X. docs, D3 examples and a stack of S.O. Questions but they all refer to the D3-Request interface and I can't find any examples using the newer D3-Fetch API as above.

Comment: Have you tried without the .stringify ?

Comment: Can you get this working in other contexts, e.g. using curl instead of d3-fetch? What error message is the server returning?

Comment: @I_alarmed_alien, I was getting 4XX's with no descriptive information on the client side. I posted the fix that got me going again. Thanks for the pointers though both to you and dkarchmer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dkarchmer I figured I needed more information on the server side. The following mixin was rather useful for showing both the data received and transmitted.

```
class AjaxLoggingMixin(object):

    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
        print(response.data)
        return super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
```

It turns out the requests were going through correctly but were malformed and Django was rejecting them returning either 4XX error codes. In particular

- 403 results when the user isn't authenticated or user authentication isn't setup properly.
- 400 results when the data is malformed.