# AngularJS HTTP post to PHP and undefined

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

I have a form with the tag `ng-submit="login()`

The function gets called fine in javascript.

```
function LoginForm($scope, $http)
{
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';

    $scope.email    = "fsdg@sdf.com";
    $scope.password = "1234";

    $scope.login = function()
    {
        data = {
            'email' : $scope.email,
            'password' : $scope.password
        };

        $http.post('resources/curl.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            console.log(status + ' - ' + data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            console.log('error');
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting a 200 OK response back from the PHP file, however, the returned data is saying that `email` and `password` are undefined. This is all the php I have

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass  = $_POST['password'];
echo $email;
?>
```

Any idea why I am getting undefined `POST` values?

**EDIT**

I wanted to point out since this seems to be a popular question (yet it is old), `.success` and `.error` have been deprecated and you should use `.then` as @James Gentes pointed out in the commments

Comment: Did you look at the network tab of your developer tools? What value is passed in `$http`?

Comment: In the network tab, under `Form-Data` it says `{"email":"fsdg@sdf.com","password":"1234"}`

Comment: @Ronnie Seems like JSON. Try `print_r($_POST);` and then try `json_decode()` on the right index

Comment: Coming from jQuery that is how I would normally POST data. I just tried `print_r($_POST);` and I got `array()`

Comment: Only `array()`? Without contents?

Comment: correct. It looks like its not posting anything apparently

Comment: @Ronnie Try `echo 'Test';` If you're not getting "Test" then maybe you're not pointing to the right file `resources/curl.php` ?

Comment: `echo 'test';` works fine. I am certainly pointing to the right file

Comment: Note that .success and .error have been deprecated and replaced with .then (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: The `.success` and `.error` methods have been [removed form AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6).

Comment: @georgeawg yes, as noted on my edit from 2015

Answer (score 228, accepted):

angularjs `.post()` defaults the Content-type header to `application/json`. You are overriding this to pass form-encoded data, however you are not changing your `data` value to pass an appropriate query string, so PHP is not populating `$_POST` as you expect.

My suggestion would be to just use the default angularjs setting of `application/json` as header, read the raw input in PHP, and then deserialize the JSON.

That can be achieved in PHP like this:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$email = $request->email;
$pass = $request->password;
```

Alternately, if you are heavily relying on `$_POST` functionality, you can form a query string like `email=someemail@email.com&password=somepassword` and send that as data. Make sure that this query string is URL encoded. If manually built (as opposed to using something like `jQuery.serialize()`), Javascript's `encodeURIComponent()` should do the trick for you.

Comment: Not disrespecting your knowledge, but using `file_get_contents("php://input");` seems kind of like a hack, no? I have never heard of this. What needs to happen so I can just reference it like `$_POST['email'];`

Comment: or was that the second part of your answer?

Comment: @Ronnie It is not a hack.  It really depends on how you want to set up your web service. If you want to send and retrieve JSON, you need to work with raw input as `$_POST` will not be populated.

Comment: ok, this makes sense. I am going to use your suggested solution. Thanks Mike and everyone else

Comment: @Ronnie: Don't forget to properly encode query string parameters using `encodeURIComponent`. E.g., `@` should be changed in `%40`.

Comment: Thanks Marcel, I will keep that in mind, but I am not using the query string method. I am using the `file_get_contente(..etc);` solution. Mike's suggested solution

Comment: Serialize without JQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: @lepe It is not clear to me how the linked question/answer relates to my answer.  There is no discussion of needing to serialize a javascript object here.

Comment: @MikeBrant: Thank you for pointing it out. You commented about "encodeURIComponent" and jQuery.serialize(), but it may be easier to show an example on how to achieve it without relying on jQuery. So that link complements your answer.

Comment: I guess I'll ask here since you seem to be more active.. what's the downside of using @valmarv 's answer over yours? (If there is any)

Comment: @lascort there is really not much of a difference to the solutions really. In my solution, I am not populating the data into $_POST, preferring a user-defined variable instead. In a general, this makes more sense to me in that when working with JSON-serialized data, you might be working wth objects, or numerically-indexed arrays. I wouldn't suggest adding a numerically-Indexed array to $_POST, as this would be an atypical use.  I also generally shy away from putting data into any of the superglobals that are used for input data.

Comment: maybe a mention of the `$maxlen` parameter to give developer more granular control of how much data it will load into memory for a given request. Especially if your server has a high max post size in the webserver or php daemon, granular control for each route can minimize the memory impact of malicious requests.

Comment: @Ben10 This functionality should has nothing to do with SSL.  You likely have a problem with either mixed SSL/non-SSL content, invalid/untrusted cert, or similar.

Comment: Should one prefer `application/json` over the `urlencoded` Content-Type? I cannot decide as there is a angularjs `$httpParamSerializer` e.g. to help with conversion.

Comment: @ItsmeJulian there is no absolute right answer. It might really depend on how your application is architected. If your are interacting with a REST service that is consuming/delivering JSON, then I would probably stick with JSON content type. If I were working largely with an endpoint the can produce HTML or HTML fragments or uses basic form posting as fallback to AJAX, then I might be inclined to stick with form encoding.

Answer (score 41):

I do it on the server side, at the begining of my init file, works like a charm and you don't have to do anything in angular or existing php code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST))
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: you should cast your result in case $_POST is empty : `$_POST = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)`.

Comment: I don't really get why PHP guys didn't implement this themselves, They really expect url-encoded posts always??

Comment: @Bludream I don't get why anyone expects PHP to do what is expected. It violates the principle of least-surprise all the time.

Comment: This seems like a very fragile approach unless you absolutely know that the POSTed data represents an associative array (an object representation in JSON).  What if the JSON contained a numerically-indexed array representation?  `$_POST` would end up getting a numerically indexed array in this cases, something that would be very unexpected behavior in other part of the system that rely upon consistent `$_POST` superglobal behavior.

Comment: I only use this in angular powered applications, of course, and I validate my POST data very thoroughly, don't see how can this be a problem...

Answer (score 15):

In the API I am developing I have a base controller and inside its __construct() method I have the following:

```
if(isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) && strpos($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"], "application/json") !== false) {
    $_POST = array_merge($_POST, (array) json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true));
}
```

This allows me to simply reference the json data as $_POST["var"] when needed. Works great.

That way if an authenticated user connects with a library such a jQuery that sends post data with a default of Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded or Content-Type: application/json the API will respond without error and will make the API a little more developer friendly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

Because PHP does not natively accept JSON `'application/json'` One approach is to update your headers and parameters from angular so that your api can use the data directly.

**First**, Parameterize your data:

```
data: $.param({ "foo": $scope.fooValue })
```

**Then**, add the following to your `$http`

```
 headers: {
     'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
 },
```

*If all of your requests are going to PHP the parameters can be set globaly in the configuration as follows:*

```
myApp.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Angular Js Demo Code :-

```
angular.module('ModuleName',[]).controller('main', ['$http', function($http){

                var formData = { password: 'test pwd', email : 'test email' };
                var postData = 'myData='+JSON.stringify(formData);
                $http({
                        method : 'POST',
                        url : 'resources/curl.php',
                        data: postData,
                        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}  

                }).success(function(res){
                        console.log(res);
                }).error(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
        });

        }]);
```

Server Side Code :-

```
<?php


// it will print whole json string, which you access after json_decocde in php
$myData = json_decode($_POST['myData']);
print_r($myData);

?>
```

Due to angular behaviour there is no direct method for normal post behaviour at PHP server, so you have to manage it in json objects.

Comment: This is incorrect.  See answers above where JSON is read directly from PHP raw input.  This is much more straightforward than mixing JSON into query string.

Comment: The `.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated and have been removed from the AngularJS framework.

Answer (score 6):

You need to deserialize your form data before passing it as the second parameter to .post (). You can achieve this using jQuery's  $.param (data) method.
Then you will be able to on server side to reference it like $.POST ['email'];

Answer (score 6):

This is the best solution (IMO) as it requires no jQuery and no JSON decode:

Source:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179373
and: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714899/196507

Summary:

```
//Replacement of jQuery.param
var serialize = function(obj, prefix) {
  var str = [];
  for(var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
      str.push(typeof v == "object" ?
        serialize(v, k) :
        encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
    }
  }
  return str.join("&");
};

//Your AngularJS application:
var app = angular.module('foo', []);

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    // send all requests payload as query string
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data){
        if (data === undefined) {
            return data;
        }
        return serialize(data);
    };

    // set all post requests content type
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
});
```

Example:

```
...
   var data = { id: 'some_id', name : 'some_name' };
   $http.post(my_php_url,data).success(function(data){
        // It works!
   }).error(function() {
        // :(
   });
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST["id"];
?>
```

Comment: What about: `JSON.stringify('{ id: 'some_id', name : 'some_name' }')` or `$httpParamSerializer` for client-side conversion?

Answer (score 5):

It's an old question but it worth to mention that in Angular 1.4 $httpParamSerializer is added and when using $http.post, if we use $httpParamSerializer(params) to pass the parameters, everything works like a regular post request and no JSON deserializing is needed on server side.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer

Answer (score 1):

It took me hours to understand that while working with Angular and PHP.
Post data was not going to PHP in $_POST

in PHP code do the following. 
- Create a variable $angular_post_params
- Then do the following 
`$angular_http_params = (array)json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')));`

now you can access your parameters like you do from $_POST

`$angular_http_params["key"]`

in case you were wondering about javascript....this is what i used

```
    var myApp = angular.module('appUsers', []);
    //var post_params = $.param({ request_type: "getListOfUsersWithRolesInfo" });
    var dataObj = {
        task_to_perform: 'getListOfUsersWithRolesInfo'
    };

    myApp.controller('ctrlListOfUsers', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_processor_url,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: dataObj,
            //transformRequest: function(){},
            timeout: 30000,
            cache: false
        }).
        success(function (rsp) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(rsp);
        }).
        error(function (rsp) {
            console.log("error");
        });
    });
```

Comment: for newbies ... dont forget to have ng-app and ng-controller directives added to your content holder container on the page :)

Comment: The `.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated and have been removed from the AngularJS framework.