# angular $http.post - data not showing in $_POST array on target .php page

Tags: http, angularjs, post

the var 'id' doesnt show up in the $_POST array on the target .php page. Can nay one point me in the right direction?

```
$http.post("php/get_venue.php", { id: "108" })
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("success", data);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("error", data, status, headers, config);
});
```

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined

Comment: Agree. Angular `$http` sends Request Body, so you'll have to read it with `file_get_contents("php://input");`