# Javascript object to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

I am posting JavaScript objects to my PHP backend but I am not able to retrieve the data.

I posted this java-script object:

```
{"name":"Mastermold"}
```

I am trying to access name like this:

```
$name= $_POST["name"];
```

The error is:

> {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index: name","file":"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\app\controllers\JournalsController.php","line":34}}

---

```
saveMongoJournal=function(theJournal,doThis) {
                        journalRoute="http://localhost/public/journals"
                        $http.post(journalRoute,theJournal).success(doThis);

                        };

$scope.clicky= function(){
        saveMongoJournal( {name: "mastermold"},alertReply);

                };




$_POST['name'];
```

Comment: You posted it how? *Also, I wish people would comment instead of just downvoting. It's not constructive*

Comment: We need informations. How do you post the javascript object, what is the PHP script.

Comment: if you have opening double quote, closing quote should be double as well

Comment: The PHP is fine (except for the syntax error that was in the question). The error shows that `$_POST['name']` is expected to exist. We only need to see how it's trying to be posted.

Comment: The `$_POST` key (`name`) does not end with the proper quote, it's ending with an apostrophe, so simply fix it by doing `$_POST['name']`. I'm not a JS expert, but I tend not to enclose the object key in quotes, I keep it like `{name: "Mastermold"}`. Not sure if this would make a difference here thought.

Comment: if you send the javascript object as string like you posted you want to convert it with json_decode to use it as an object in php again, alternatively: check the content of $_POST with var_dump($_POST); and see what is in there and if you correctly send the data

Comment: Show us the code that does the post.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing

Comment: the http method is from angular: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this (Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15485690/741747))

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo $data->name;
```