# I have a post form that submits but "$_POST" variable is empty even though my web inspector indicates otherwise

Tags: php, post, form-submit

Here is my html:

```
<form id="quant" method="POST" action="/portfolio" name="trans">

        <div class="modal-body">
        Shares : <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="quantity">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']); ?>" name="stock">
        <input type="submit" name="val" value="Confirm Transaction" class="btn btn-primary">

        <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Here is an image of my web inspector showing that in fact that data was requested:

[image: Image of request data]

I have been trying to figure out why this has not been working for a long time, any suggestions would be appreciated.

The Code:

```
if(isset($_POST["quantity"])) {
    var_dump($_POST);
```

which returns nothing

Comment: Show us your form tag

Comment: Also your code will help.

Comment: `echo var_dump($_POST)` will not work. Return type of var_dump is void. Just use `var_dump()`

Comment: Your action says 'action="/portfolio"'... where are you sending the form to? Shouldn't it be: action="portfolio.php" or action="../portfolio.php"?

Comment: removed the echo, still returns an empty array

Comment: @GaryHayes the directory points to file called index.php

Comment: Then you need a slash after it to let it know it is a folder and not a file: action="/portfolio/"

Comment: That worked!  What I don't understand is why a GET form I have on the same page worked without the added slash… @GaryHayes

Comment: Possibly because GET sends the data in the url, so the browser knew how to interpret the error.

Comment: How can I mark this as answered if the answer was a comment?

Comment: I made the comment into an answer

Comment: When you just request `/portfolio`, your (normally configured) web server will send your browser a _redirect_ header asking it to request `/portfolio/` instead. And since the browser follows that redirect by making a _GET_ request for `/portfolio/`, your POST data is lost. (With GET as form method in the first place, your browser has requested `/portfolio?foo=bar` at first, and the server told it to ask for `/portfolio/?foo=bar` instead – that’s why your data was not lost when using GET.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you need a slash after it to let it know it is a folder and not a file: action="/portfolio/"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like AngularJS to submit your form, it doesn't send POST data the typical way. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined).