# serialize data from AJAX request to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs, post

My problem is very common. I must be doing some silly mistake somewhere but I am not able to figure it out.

I am send my form data in serialized form but it is not coming to PHP at all.

Angular JS code:

```
saveForm: function() {
    var str = $('#feedbackForm').serializeArray();
    alert(JSON.stringify(str)); // here I am getting my data properly
    return $http({
        method  :'POST',
        url:'http://localhost/api?module=form&app_id=APP001&action=save&formid=2&user_id=3',
        data: str
    });
}
```

PHP

```
$log->info($_REQUEST); // I am getting all GET parameters correctly
```

tried this also

```
$log->info($_POST);
```

it is not printing my data. why?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined

Comment: I tried the same thing...I don't know why is it not working :(

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `$http` will send the data as `application/json`, which won't be recognized by the `$_POST` in PHP.

You have to choose either sending the data as form data like this:

```
return $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost/api?module=form&app_id=APP001&action=save&formid=2&user_id=3',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data: str
});
```

Or don't use the `$_POST` but read and parse input directly in PHP like this:

```
$rawInput = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($rawInput);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I put this PHP part as it is? or I need to replace anything? because I copied as it is..it is showing blank

Comment: If you choose the latter, you have to use the `$data` as an PHP json object like this `$data->name`, `$data->email`.

Comment: it is not working still :(..The way I m serializing my form and sending it to php is correct?..can you give me some sample program..that would be really helpful.