# angularjs form post to array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, serialization, xmlhttprequest

I try to sending a form post as array in angularjs $http.

```
 //this is how i serialize it
 $("#formTest").serializeArray().map(function(x){data[x.name] = x.value;});
```

and if i put it into console.log. the result is

```
products[0][code]   azizi-hoho
products[0][price_total]    44
products[0][price_unit] 3
```

now i try to post those value using angular $http with `post` method. Then when i inspect the post data. it actually sending it like this.

```
products%5B0%5D%5Bcode%5D=azizi-hohoproducts%5B0%5D%5Bprice_total%5D=44products%5B0%5D%5Bprice_unit%5D=3
```

On the server side, if the post is successfull. The post data will then be grabbed by

```
$products = json_decode($_POST['products']);
```

But on this case, this doesn't happen, how do i make `$_POST['products']` containing those data that i post.

Comment: why u are using jquery  ?

Comment: because in angularjs, it is very tricky to use http post. So sometime jquery might be a life saver

Comment: Please don't use jquery if you don't have to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15485690/736967