# Use a variable in PhP script passed by $http.post

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, http

In angular im using `$http.post` for sending an id to a php script in order to use this id for a mysql request.

This is my controller:

```
function ProjectDetailsCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout, getGoodIdProjectDetails) {

    $scope.idProjectDetails = getGoodIdProjectDetails.getId(); //Getting id project

    $scope.$emit('LOAD')
    $scope.url = 'scripts/findProjectDetails.php';

    $http.post($scope.url, { "idProject" : $scope.idProjectDetails}).
    success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.projectDetails = {};
        $scope.projectDetails.details = data;
        $scope.$emit('UNLOAD')
    })
    .
    error(function(data, status) {
        $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
        $scope.status = status;         
    });
}
```

`idProjectDetails` is a number.

Then the Php script :

```
<?php
$idProject = json_decode($_POST['idProject']);
```

Php script returns that `$idProject` is undefined.

Can you help me with this ?

Edit : I tried this way but my app crashed with this :

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'scripts/findProjectDetails.php',
    data: "idProject" : $scope.idProjectDetails  
}).success(function(data, status) {
    $scope.projectDetails = {};
    $scope.projectDetails.details = data;
    console.log(projectDetails.details);
    $scope.$emit('UNLOAD')
})
.
error(function(data, status) {
    $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
    $scope.status = status;         
});
```

With the first example, in Chrome console, the "request playload" contain this : `{idProject:1}` `idProject:1` so I assume my variable is correctly passed through the php script?

Comment: `json_decode($_POST['idProject']);` doesn't make sense, if `$scope.idProjectDetails` is a number as you have stated.

Comment: Okay, $scope.idprojectDetails is definitly a number, so what make sense ?

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, according to the quote in the below answer. but i think you should just use it as a number, don't decode it.

Comment: Same problem appear if i don't decode

Comment: Open your console and inspect the network request.

Comment: Status code show '200 ok' and 'request payload' show idProject : 1

Comment: `idProject : 1`, or `{"idProject": 1}`, important difference.

Comment: If in the network request i click on 'view source' then it's {"idProject":1}

Comment: then you won't be able to read the response data as a post variable, you'll have to get it from the request body and then decode it. An example of doing so is in the 2nd link of jean's answer.

Comment: Thw for helping, im not sure to understand how to get it from the request body, pls explain :)

Comment: Thx a lot, thats seems to work, my query works now, nice help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is much confusion among newcomers to AngularJS as to why the $http service shorthand functions ($http.post(), etc.) don’t appear to be swappable with the jQuery equivalents (jQuery.post(), etc.) The difference is in how jQuery and AngularJS serialize and transmit the data. Fundamentally, the problem lies with your server language of choice being unable to understand AngularJS’s transmission natively ... By default, jQuery transmits data using Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded and the familiar foo=bar&baz=moe serialization. AngularJS, however, transmits data using Content-Type: application/json and { "foo": "bar", "baz": "moe" } JSON serialization, which unfortunately some Web server languages—notably PHP—do not unserialize natively.

So concretely, your $_POST variable is empty !

To go through this problem there're 2 solutions:

- [Change the data format in Angular config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data#answer-20276775)
- [Change the way to get the datas with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined#answer-15485690)(Deprecated but works)

I haven't invented anything here, just linking...
Hope it'll help.