# $http post to PHP with Angular not working

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm having a problem with getting data over to my PHP file after decoding Json and I am getting an error. Can someone help me to know where I am going wrong?

app.js

```
 $scope.formPost = function(){


        $http.post('sendmail.php',{msg: 'helo'})
            .success(function(data,status,headers,config){


                console.log('data: ' + data);
                console.log('status: ' + status);
                console.log('headers: ' + headers);

            }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){

            });


};
```

sendmail.php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

$msg = $data->msg;
echo $msg;
```

And the error message I'm getting is

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-new-project/sendmail.php on line 5

Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you getting in $data ?

Comment: using var_dump  string(0) ""
also, getting a status 200 and everything , just not showing up in the php file

Comment: What if you var_dump the file_get_contents bit?

Comment: the way you are using $http, it does not send json data, it sends simple $_POST parameters. so try doing `echo $_POST['msg']`

Comment: yes, I tried that already. Undefined index. $_POST is just empty. Not really sure what else to do here. Tried everything.

Comment: Here is alive example.....192.185.87.92/~ysaguirre/#/contact this is what is sent to sendmail.php –

Answer (score 0):

Whether this is the whole of the problem, I can't say at the moment, but you have specifically asked `json_decode()` to return an associative array by passing it a second parameter of true.

Either start using $data as an array, or get rid of the `true`.

Comment: got ride of the true, but now just getting NULL as the output of the array.

Comment: @arsenalist Currently not enough information to know why you don't have the data. See comments.

Comment: Here is alive example.....http://192.185.87.92/~ysaguirre/#/contact

this is what is sent to sendmail.php

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are sending regular form data, not json, so you can use the php superglobal `$_POST]`;

```
//$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

$msg = $_POST['msg'];
echo $msg;
```

Comment: still showing empty array when using the global POST. In my console I can see the data, however when I try to show it via the url (php) nothing is sent. The array is empty and var_dump shows NULL.

Comment: @arsenalist `". In my console I can see the data, however when I try to show it via the url (php) nothing is sent"` Please explain what you meaan by `"show it by the url"`?

Comment: I meant when I try to send it to the php file. For example, in my console I get data: object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["msg"]=>
  string(4) "helo"
}   
(this is for the data portion)
however, when sending it to sendmail.php, I am getting NULL when using var_dump... also for status getting 200 so I know it's successful.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I did to solve same issue:

```
$scope.submitData = function() { 

    var myobject = {'destination': destination, 'title': _title, 'message': _message};

    Object.toparams = function ObjecttoParams(obj) {
        var p = [];
        for (var key in obj) {
            p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
        }
        return p.join('&');
    };   

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "data/insert.php",
        data: Object.toparams(myobject)
    })

}
```

And Php:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$destination = $_POST["destination"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
```

As based to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15485690/5255820