# isset($_POST[] ) not working

Tags: php

i got this file upload.html where below code resides, and everytime i browse file and submit its failing at isset($_POST). it echoes "didn't upload", its working fine with same file in another folder. all i did was move the whole website folder content to another folder, and it stopped working.

```
   <h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="uploadxls" value="Upload File" />
</form>



<?php

include("../include/processxls.php");

date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

if (isset($_POST['uploadxls']) && !empty($_POST['uploadxls']))
{
    echo "test point";
    uploadReport();
}
else 
{
    echo "didn't upload";
}



function uploadReport()
{

$report=basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$report=str_replace(' ','|',$report);

$tmppath="uploads/".$report;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$tmppath))
    {
        echo " File upload success. Please wait while report is processed....... "; 

        processxls($tmppath);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "fail";
    }   
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried this in different browsers? Which browser are you using?

Comment: yes i tried safari, chrome and firefox

Comment: Try `print_r($_REQUEST)` and see if that gives you anything. Post your results here so we can see.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: Array ( [_ga] => GA1.2.1674518736.1434244186 [ci_session] => a:4:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"0e81f3cc1be3505255b8ef331ca058e0";s:10:"ip_address";s:13:"104.63.10.155";s:10:"user_agent";s:116:"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/600.6.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.6 Safari/600.6.3";s:13:"last_activity";i:1432694042;}a8b04db2b5f55b49b7896fb1275d9832b81c7f41 ) 
array(0) { } didn't upload

Comment: array(0) is for var_dump($_POST)

Comment: Do you have any other scripts running that could redirect a $_POST request? eg. something like a rewrite script? (any includes at the top maybe?)

Comment: using admin panel bootstrap, and using angularjs controller to load this upload page.

Comment: but if i try even without admin panel stuff and just do plain upload.html file and php that I'm including it still fails to POST

Comment: Try this: `print_r(file_get_contents("php://input"));` and see what you get.

Comment: at what point should i put that? before if statement?

Comment: Put it at the top before your `include(...);`

Comment: same thing goes to else and echoes didn't upload

Comment: Check this out, maybe it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined

Comment: Stupid question: Did you also move the `../include/processxls.php` such that its location is still appropriately relative to this php file?

Comment: yes i did, and I'm not getting php related errors, POST is just simply not happening for some reason, i made a copy of original version that is functioning to godaddy server, it didn't work and then i changed the upload.html to upload.php it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers ignore the value of submit buttons and do not send this data with the POST

Use a hidden input field instead, and then this will be submitted regardless of browser.

```
<input type='hidden' name="uploadxls" value="Upload File">
```

Comment: i did that and submit button goes away, when i select file it just sits there doesnt submit the form

Comment: You still need a submit button to submit your form. skrilled means to move the "uploadxls" to another field because not all browser submit the value of a submit button.

Comment: still same thing, the same web site content is in another folder and when i visit that url in same browser it works fine.

Comment: i even did just if ($_POST) that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

You should determine if it is a post using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST" ) {
    // Do checks and logic
}
```

That way you don't need to worry about the browser sending the submit button or using hidden values.  PHP has a built in variable for it, may as well use it.