# undefined index error when using $http.post in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am Having following lines of code in my project.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myctrl', function ($scope, $http) { 
    $http.post('temp2.php', { msg:'hello' })
    .then(function (response) {
        alert(response.data);
    }, function (response) {
          alert("error");
    });
});
```

I am accessing `msg` using `$_POST` on `temp2.php` page. But it is showing the following error `undefined index msg`. Please help me.

Comment: This does not look like an angular problem

Comment: Payload you are sending is not query string "msg=hello" . You can access {msg:'hello'} using php://input

Comment: What are the full contents of `$_POST`?

Comment: See this other stackoverflow question, already answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined

Comment: @Creator: Thanks... Its working now

Comment: @Ankit21ks Ok i have added it as an answer. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with angular part . check your php file . You are sending your data as json and it can be get in server side using\

```
 php://input .
```

$_POST will work fine if you will send payload as query string . **"msg=text"**;

For more info   [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)