# Angular JS http POST not working with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, post, request

I am developing a mobile app using Angular JS , I am trying to do a POST request to PHP server using the following $http request

```
$http({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "http://myling.wilson34.com/saveInterpreter.php",
            data: data,
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            }
        })
```

but its return an empty $_POST 
I have tried

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

but with no luck , any help with that please ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15485690/1175966

Comment: if send as form encoded need to paramterize the data see `paramSerializer ` in $http docs. Otherwise use method in link above

Comment: I am sorry but this didn't work as well

Comment: what didn't work? Need to be more specific. I use the file_get_contents() all the time with no problems ... and occasionally use form encoding also

Comment: file_get_contents() method return an empty array

Comment: then what is being sent...what is `data`? Is it defined?. look in browser dev tools network also...can inspect full reuest and see what was sent, status, returned etc

Comment: data is defined and I can see it in dev tools in network section and I tried to sent just a simple json like   data: {
                    "foo": "bar"
                }

Comment: and your variable data is an object? Will get stringified internally. And you removed the form header?