# posted value shows in firebug but while try to access the same it shows blank array

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs

1. i have used angualr js and developing a mini app for crud operation
   i ma facing issue while i send a post request it shows posted value
   in fireug console as shown in image1 but while trying to same using
   $_REQUEST or $_POST it returns blank array

Explanation..

in product.js

```
app.controller('productsCtrl',function($scope,Data){ 
$scope.changeStatus=function(product){
        $scope.status = {};
        $scope.status.status = product.status=='Active' ? 'Inactive' : 'Active';
        //Data.put('http://localhost/angularCrud/products.php',$scope.status);
        Data.put('http://localhost/angularCrud/test.php',$scope.status);
    };
});
```

in data.js

```
app.factory('Data',['$http','$location',function($http){ 
    var obj={};
obj.put=function(q,param){ //console.log(data);
    //$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
      successData = $http.post(q,param).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        return response;
      });
};

    return obj;
}]);
```

[image]

[image]

please let me know how to access the posted value of status??

Comment: obviously we're gona need more info on this, some code snippet, or more eplanation on the structure of the project, for all we know you could be setting the array to null somewhare in your program.

Comment: let me know what info you need..

Comment: the part of the code that posts the request and parts where the post might be used and where its being displayed

Comment: as @deeznutz it will require your service call and php code to show up but also you can have a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined

Comment: @deez nuts question updated with description.

Comment: @krish link you gave same as i want thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also face same problem in my app.The solution i do is

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");  //Get all data of form
$request = json_decode($data);
```

`$request` is an object array now use this like

```
$request->action  //Anything your data is
```