# Ajax call using angular js

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

I am a new Angularjs user.I am facing a problem,when i submit a signup form,I have applied validation using AngularJs. At the same time if all the input fields are valid then i have send an $http Ajax call to check the email address,already exist or not.The issue is my php file did not receive email data.

```
$http({
         method  : 'POST',
         async: false,
         url: 'http://localhost/angular/signup/emailcheck.php',
         data: { email: $scope.user.email },  // pass in data as strings
         headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
      })
      .success(function(data) 
      {
          $scope.info = data;
          if($scope.userForm.$valid && $scope.info === '0') {
                alert('our form is amazing' + $scope.info);
          }
          else{
                  alert('Already exist');
              }
      }).error(function(response,status)
      {
          console.log('ERROR HERE'+ status);
      });
```

My Php file code:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user where username = '".$email."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
//fetch tha data from the database 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
....
....
....
....
....
}
```

I have checked and found that php file did not receive email value at all.

Comment: check console log if you are getting some error?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in browser's console ?

Comment: No, there is not any error at console.i have checked it.

Comment: alert $scope.user.email before ajax request and see are you getting email?

Comment: Yes i have checked it.It shows the correct value.

Comment: This might help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs

Comment: First of all I suggest to use the right format of $http service, that is `$http(..).then(successCallback, errorCallback);` (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found that in php file,

> $_POST or $_GET will not work, to receive data.
>   Use the following:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objData = json_decode($data);
$email = $objData->email;
```

In my case it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
$http({
     method  : 'POST',
     async: false,
     url: 'http://localhost/angular/signup/emailcheck.php',
     data : $.param($scope.user),  // this will definitely wor
     headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
  })
  .success(function(data) 
  {
      $scope.info = data;
      if($scope.userForm.$valid && $scope.info === '0') {
            alert('our form is amazing' + $scope.info);
      }
      else{
              alert('Already exist');
          }
  }).error(function(response,status)
  {
      console.log('ERROR HERE'+ status);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing http://localhost from url and then see it may be CORS.

Comment: Yes, it sounds liek CORS. OP should get a browser plugin to allow it (and only use that browser for development)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: your url is pointing to localhost but has no port number, this is unusual, maybe you forgot it?

Comment: What's unusual about it? It will default to port 80 and his (Apache?) server will handle it & run his PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: $.param({
    email:$scope.user.email
})
```

Or this way: (modify the php)

[Angular HTTP post to PHP and undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined)