# Converting javascript function into $http provider in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following function below which I am trying to re-write using $http provider. The documentation shows so many different ways of doing this and I cant get it right. Here is the function:

```
function Ingest(Filename, ID, baseUrl, logger){       
  var url = baseUrl + '/php/' + 'Ingest.php';                                                                
  var dataString = 'Filename=' + encodeURIComponent(Filename) + '&ID=' + encodeURIComponent(ID);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: dataString,
    success: function(results){                  
        logger.success('Ingestion process has been finished.', '', 'Success');                                                                                 
    }
    //fail
    , error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("error:\r\n" + errorThrown);
    }            
  });
}
```

and here is a sample of $http code:

```
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: config.appBaseUrl + '/php/' + 'Ingest.php',
data: { ID: encodeURIComponent(ID), Filename: encodeURIComponent(Filename) }

}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Thank you

Comment: what's the error in the code?

Comment: In your jquery example you trying to `post` data, in your angular example you are trying to `get` data.

Comment: Well, one request is using `GET` the other one is using `POST` which one is it?

Comment: sorry, it was a typo, the error is that the PHP page is not receiving any data on the other side. I am using these 2 lines to grab the POST data:
$id   = $_POST['ID'];
$file = $_POST['Filename'];

Comment: Found my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the 1st sample you do a post, in the second a get.

You can just use shortcut method provided by $http.

```
$http.post( config.appBaseUrl + '/php/' + 'Ingest.php',  Filename: encodeURIComponent(Filename), ID: encodeURIComponent(ID)).then(function(response){

}, function(rejection){

});
```

If you want to set some specific configuration for the $http (headers,...) use the 3rd argument of the functions.

Note that shortcut post/put have a second argument for request body, 3rd for configurations.Delete and get does not have request body argument so configuration are the 2nd argument of the function.