# Yii 1.1.17: CSRF token validation fails with POST via Angular Controller

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, yii, csrf

I have an Yii application in which I have a link (outside a form) triggering an Angular controller posting some data. The problem is that Yii does not validate the CSRF token when that happens.

My raw url looks like this:

```
<a id="yt1" href="#" ng-click="markAllAsRead(23, '1eb4e3ac755e22939a0fc8d5ea0e9bacb453319a')" title="Read All" tooltips-size="small" tooltips="1" class="notification-tool ng-isolate-scope"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

My Angular controller calls an angular service which looks like this:

```
notificationsService.markAllAsRead = function (user_id, csrf) {
        var dataObject = {
            user_id: user_id,
            YII_CSRF_TOKEN: csrf
        };

        $http.post("/api/notifications/readAll", dataObject).success(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    };
```

The POST request looks liek this:
[image: POST request via ajax]

If I disable the CSRF validation the call succeeds.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**COMPLETE ANSWER:**

After some investigation I noticed that the `$_POST` (also Yii's `$request->getPost()`) was actually empty, even though Angular was posting data. Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15485690/1475898) on stackoverflow it seems that it actually is an issue that has to do with Angular JS and its' default behavior to post as `apllication/json` (well, maybe not exactly an issue). As suggested by the marked answer to this question and based on the suggestion on the linked answer, I ended up overriding the `CHttpRequest` class from Yii as follows:

```
class AppRequest extends CHttpRequest
{
    public function validateCsrfToken($event)
    {
        if ($this->getIsPostRequest() ||
            $this->getIsPutRequest() ||
            $this->getIsPatchRequest() ||
            $this->getIsDeleteRequest()
        ) {
            $cookies = $this->getCookies();

            $method = $this->getRequestType();
            switch ($method) {
                case 'POST':
                    if (empty($this->getPost($this->csrfTokenName))) {
                        $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);;
                        $userToken = $input[$this->csrfTokenName];
                    } else {
                        $userToken = $this->getPost($this->csrfTokenName);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'PUT':
                    if (empty($this->getPut($this->csrfTokenName))) {
                        $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);;
                        $userToken = $input[$this->csrfTokenName];
                    } else {
                        $userToken = $this->getPut($this->csrfTokenName);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'PATCH':
                    if (empty($this->getPatch($this->csrfTokenName))) {
                        $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);;
                        $userToken = $input[$this->csrfTokenName];
                    } else {
                        $userToken = $this->getPatch($this->csrfTokenName);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'DELETE':
                    if (empty($this->getDelete($this->csrfTokenName))) {
                        $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);;
                        $userToken = $input[$this->csrfTokenName];
                    } else {
                        $userToken = $this->getDelete($this->csrfTokenName);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            if (!empty($userToken) && $cookies->contains($this->csrfTokenName)) {
                $cookieToken = $cookies->itemAt($this->csrfTokenName)->value;
                $valid = $cookieToken === $userToken;
            } else
                $valid = false;
            if (!$valid)
                throw new CHttpException(400, Yii::t('yii', 'The CSRF token could not be verified.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: status `400` means something went wrong on server side..may be desired parameter are not passing correctly from body.

Comment: @PankajParkar if i disable the csrf verification, it works.

Comment: You could add it as an answer..if you like it to.

Comment: @PankajParkar well that is not an answer. What i really mean is that without the CSRF validation there is no error. However, I need the validation to be enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will look at `CHttpRequest` and watch how validation performed, you will understand problem.

```
public function validateCsrfToken($event)
{
    if ($this->getIsPostRequest() ||
        $this->getIsPutRequest() ||
        $this->getIsPatchRequest() ||
        $this->getIsDeleteRequest())
    {
        $cookies=$this->getCookies();
        $method=$this->getRequestType();
        switch($method)
        {
            case 'POST':
                $userToken=$this->getPost($this->csrfTokenName);
            break;
            case 'PUT':
                $userToken=$this->getPut($this->csrfTokenName);
            break;
            case 'PATCH':
                $userToken=$this->getPatch($this->csrfTokenName);
            break;
            case 'DELETE':
                $userToken=$this->getDelete($this->csrfTokenName);
        }
        if (!empty($userToken) && $cookies->contains($this->csrfTokenName))
        {
            $cookieToken=$cookies->itemAt($this->csrfTokenName)->value;
            $valid=$cookieToken===$userToken;
        }
        else
            $valid = false;
        if (!$valid)
            throw new CHttpException(400,Yii::t('yii','The CSRF token could not be verified.'));
    }
}
```

So to make `CSRF` validation work we need 2 conditions:

1. Client must be eligible to send a request with cookie and accept cookies.
2. We need to pass token with our request.

2nd condition in your case not working. You'r passing `json` to request body, and `Yii` trying to get token from post:

```
$userToken=$this->getPost($this->csrfTokenName);
```

To change this behavior, you need to override `CHttpRequest` and change config file to use your `Request` class, e.g.

```
  'components' => array(
    'request' => array(
        'class' => 'application.components.HttpRequest',
        'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
    ),
  ),
```

Hope this will help with understanding of what's happening when CSRF validation performed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will have a look later and mark your answer if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The issue is now fixed and I updated my question with the complete answer.