# Angular post request to php failed

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a simple form with two fields.

```
<form name="save" ng-submit="sap.saved(save.$valid)" novalidate>

        <div class="form-group" >
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="sap.name" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" >
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model="sap.email" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="save.$invalid || sap.dataLoading">Save</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

I'm trying to post these values to a php page using POST request.

```
                $http({
                  method: 'post',
                  url: 'save.php',
                  data: $scope.vm,
                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                })
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
                {
                    if(data.success)
                    {
                        alert('valid');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('invalid 1');
                    }
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
                {
                    alert('invalid 2');
                });
```

And in save.php file, I'm fetching the values like this:

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
```

But response I get is undefned variable name. That's a PHP notice. But when I try to POST these values from POSTman client, it works.
Is there anything wrong with the method I choose to POST data?

P.S: i didn't post entire controller. Just http request part is included here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same situation where `$_POST()` did't worked out!

trying to fetch raw data with:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))
```

might be helpful.

**Update:**

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined) explains why $_POST variable is not populated in php 
when data is posted with angular!