# AngularJS, PHP and Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm trying to fill out the form then pass the data through a angular controller to a php file....doesn't seem to be working. sometimes I bet blank entries into Mysqli when I more it around but I cant seem to make it work.

I know it has something to do with the form I just cant figure it out, if I put in a more simple text box example it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="final.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">function init() {calendar.set("date");}</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<body>
<header>
<div class="row">
<img src="Final.png" alt="company logo">
</div>
</div>
<div class="top-bar" id="main-menu">
<ul class="menu vertical medium-horizontal expanded medium-text-center">
<li><a href="Home.php">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="Dad.php">Dad</a></li>
<li><a href="Mom.php">Mom</a></li>
<li><a href="Son.php">Son</a></li>
<li><a href="Daughter.php">Daughter</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
header>
<body onload="init()">
<div align="center" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="studentcontroller">
     <form id ="" action="" method="post" >
         <h2>Enter New Chore</h2> 
       <table>
        <tr>
         <td>Name :</td> <td>
         <select name="user" style="Color: Black" required ng-model="DName">
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Person.</option>
            <option value="Mom">Mom</option>
            <option value="Dad">Dad</option>
            <option value="Son">Son</option>
            <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
            </select>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Chore Title :</td><td><input type = "text" name = "choretitle" class = "box" style="width: 300px;"required  ng-model="DTitle"></td><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Due Date :</td><td><input type="text"  name="date" id="date"style="width: 300px;"required ng-model="DDate"></td><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Chore Description  :</td><td><textarea name="desc" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="256" style="width: 300px;" ng-model="DDesc"></textarea><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><button type="submit" name="btn-add"  ng-click="insertdata()">Add Chore</button></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
        </form>
        </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.controller("studentcontroller",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.insertdata = function() {
        $http.post("insert.php",{'DName':$scope.DName,'DTitle':$scope.DTitle,'DDate':$scope.DDate,'DDesc':$scope.DDesc})
        .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            console.log("Inserted Successfully!");          
        });
    }
});
</script>  

</body>
<footer id="footer">
<div class="row expanded">
<div class="medium-8 columns">
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Partner</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="medium-6 columns">
<ul class="menu align-right">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</footer>

////PHP
<?php 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$assingedTo = $data->DName;
$choreName = $data->DTitle;
$choreDesc = $data->DDesc;
$dueDate = $data->DDate;
$status = "Open";  
$DBConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "qwerty", "chores");
$sql =  "insert statement"
$result = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $sql);
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the data that is sent in `insert.php`? With `print_r($_POST)`, for example.

Comment: yea, nothing shows up

Comment: Hm, does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15485690/1781026 I remember I had a similar problem once, not sure what caused it though.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I code forms when using angular PHP. Try to fetch the data into the controller as one Javascript object.

```
<form ng-submit="submitChores(chores)" >
     <h2>Enter New Chore</h2> 
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Name :</td> <td>
     <select name="user" style="Color: Black" required ng-model="chores.DName">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Person.</option>
        <option value="Mom">Mom</option>
        <option value="Dad">Dad</option>
        <option value="Son">Son</option>
        <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
        </select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Chore Title :</td><td><input type = "text" name = "choretitle" class = "box" style="width: 300px;"required  ng-model="chores.DTitle"></td><br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Due Date :</td><td><input type="text"  name="date" id="date"style="width: 300px;"required ng-model="chores.DDate"></td><br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Chore Description  :</td><td><textarea name="desc" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="256" style="width: 300px;" ng-model="chores.DDesc"></textarea><br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><button type="submit" name="btn-add">Add Chore</button></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
    </form>
```

Controller

```
app.controller("studentcontroller",function($scope,$http){
$scope.submitChores = function(data){
       var $data = angular.toJson(data);
$http.post("insert.php",$data)
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        console.log("Inserted Successfully!");          
    });
}

});
```

This how the forms work for me and there has never been a single instance when I couldn't fetch the data in the PHP file. Happy Coding