# ionic get Multi objects from array

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

i have ionic app that send order details by email the email include the item name and size and Qty but when there is multi items in the cart it only sends the last item in the car details 
here is my controller code

```js
.controller('checkoutCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicPopup','$http','SERVER','sharedCartService',// The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, $http, SERVER, sharedCartService) {
  $scope.cart=sharedCartService.cart;
  $scope.total_qty=sharedCartService.total_qty;
  $scope.total_amount=sharedCartService.total_amount;
  $scope.data = {};
var itemNames ={};

  $scope.submit = function(){
      var link = 'http://www.myweb.net/catzOrderEmail.php';

      for( var i = 0, len = $scope.cart.length; i < len; i++ ) {

        itemNames = $scope.cart[i].cart_item_title;
        alert(itemNames);
        

     }

      $http.post(link, {
        Item_Name : itemNames ,//$scope.itemName,
        Item_size : $scope.data.Size,
        Item_qty : $scope.data.Qty,

        total_qty : $scope.total_qty,
        total_amount : $scope.total_amount,
        FirstName : $scope.data.FirstName,
        LastName : $scope.data.LastName,
        Email : $scope.data.Email,
        Country : $scope.data.Country,
        City : $scope.data.City,
        Street : $scope.data.Street,
        Zip : $scope.data.Zip,
        Phone : $scope.data.Phone
      }).then(function (res){
        this.myForm.reset();
        $state.go('home');
      });

  };

}])
```

```html
<?php
require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class
//require_once("geoiploc.php"); // Must include this
require_once("conf.php");
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 if (isset($postdata)) {
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
  $request  = json_decode($postdata);
    $SubInput = "New Order";

  $Item_Name = $request->Item_Name;
    $Item_size = $request->Item_size;
    $Item_qty = $request->Item_qty;
  $total_qty = $request->total_qty;
  $total_amount = $request->total_amount;
    $FirstName = $request->FirstName;
    $LastName = $request->LastName;
    $Email = $request->Email;
    $Country = $request->Country;
    $City = $request->City;
    $Street = $request->Street;
    $Zip = $request->Zip;
    $Phone = $request->Phone;


    $to    = "info@catzgear.net";
    $hourdiff   = "3";
    $timeadjust  = ($hourdiff * 3600);
    $date    = date("d-m-Y");
    $MsTime   = date("H:i:s",time() + $timeadjust);
    //$userip    = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    //$countryName = getCountryFromIP($userip, " NamE ");
    $message   = "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
      <tr>
        <td align='center' valign='top' bgcolor='#ababab' style='background-color:#ababab;'><br>
        <br>
        <table width='600' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
          <tr>
            <td align='left' valign='top'><img src='http://www.metalvoice.tv/images/maintop.png' width='600' height='17' style='display:block;'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align='left' valign='top' bgcolor='#ffffff' style='background-color:#ffffff;'>
      <table width='570' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='margin-bottom:15px;'>
              <tr>
                <td align='left' valign='middle' style='padding:10px;'></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table width='570' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='margin-bottom:15px;'>
                <tr>
                  <td width='360' align='left' valign='middle' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#4e4e4e; font-size:13px; padding-right:10px;'>
                  <div style='font-size:20px;'>
       Date:  $date<br><br>
       Time:  $MsTime<br><br>
       Item Name:  $Item_Name<br><br>
          Item size:  $Item_size<br><br>
          Item Qty:  $Item_qty<br><br>
          total qty: $total_qty<br><br>
          total Amount: $total_amount<br><br>
          First Name: $FirstName<br><br>
          Last Name: $LastName<br><br>
          Email: $Email<br><br>
          Country : $Country<br><br>
          City: $City<br><br>
          Street: $Street<br><br>
          Zip: $Zip<br><br>
       Phone: $Phone <br>

                  </div>
                  </td>
                  <td align='right' valign='middle'><table width='210' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
       </td>
          </tr>
         </tr>
          </table>

        <br>
        <br></td>
    </table> ";
  // if ($Item_Name != "" ||
    //     $FirstName != "" ||
    //     $LastName != "" ||
    //     $Email != "" ||
    //     $Country != "" ||
    //     $City != "" ||
    //     $Street != "" ||
    //     $Zip != "" ||
    //     $Phone != ""
    //     ) {
      // Instantiate Class
      $mail = new PHPMailer();
      // Set up SMTP
      $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection
      $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization
     // $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection
      $mail->Host = "mail.catzgear.net";  //Gmail SMTP server address
      $mail->Port = 25;  //Gmail SMTP port
      $mail->Encoding = '7bit';

      // Authentication
      $mail->Username   = "info@catzgear.net"; // Your full Gmail address
      $mail->Password   = $MyPass; // Your Gmail password

      // Compose
      $mail->SetFrom($Email, $FirstName);
      $mail->Subject = $SubInput;      // Subject (which isn't required)
      $mail->MsgHTML($message);

      // Send To
      $mail->AddAddress($to, "Catz Gear"); // Where to send it - Recipient
      $result = $mail->Send();  // Send!
    $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';
    unset($mail);

  }
 // else {
 //  echo "Sending Failed!";
 // }
?>
```

how can i get all the items names in the cart

best regards

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are only sending last element In you API, for loop is executing first , at the end there is only last element in
itemNames , And you are sending that to php.

So there are two things you can do ,

1. Call ajax inside loop (not good)
2. Push all those elements together and then send it.

   itemNames.push($scope.cart[i].cart_item_title);

for this make sure itemNames is an array . And Do your thing in php with this array object.

Hopes It will make sense to you

Comment: If it works .. please upvote and choose this as correct answer .. thanks