# I cannot get the value i send using http post in Angular2 to my PHP backend

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, angular, ionic2

The below code is angular2 form submission code,i am sending a test username and password

```
logForm(formData){
console.log('Form data is ', formData.title);
 var link = 'http://test/index.php/api/userAuth';
 var headers = new Headers();
 headers.append("Content Type","application/json"); 

    var data = JSON.stringify({
      username:'user',
      password:'user123'
    }); 

    this.http.post(link,data,headers)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.json());
    });
}
```

The PHP side is in codeigniter using REST architecture, php code is given below

```
function userAuth_post() {

    if (($this->post('username') == '') || ($this->post('password') == '')) {
        $this->response(array('message' => 'Network Error! Try Again!!!'), 200);
    }else{
        $this->response(array('message' => 'Success'), 200);
    }
}
```

Now i am receiving  "**Network Error! Try Again!!!**", i should be getting "**Success**".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15485354/1220930

Comment: Thanks for the answer, got it working using
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (isset($postdata)) {
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$userName = $request->username;
$userPass = $request->password;

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  I missed the point that it's input stream

Try this instead:

$this->input->input_stream('field');

```
if ( ! $this->input->input_stream('username') || ! $this->input->input_stream('password')) {
    $this->response(array('message' => 'Network Error! Try Again!!!'), 200);
}else{
    $this->response(array('message' => 'Success'), 200);
}
```

this is how you can get `php://input` in CodeIgniter:

$this->input->raw_input_stream;

Read more: [Here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#using-the-php-input-stream)

Comment: i tried using 
    $this->input->post('field');
still not receiving the username and password at the backend, i am using REST architecture

Comment: $postdata = $this->input->raw_input_stream;
if (isset($postdata)) {
 $request = json_decode($postdata);
$userName = $request->username;
$userPass = $request->password;
 }
This worked

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using

```
function userAuth_post() {

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($postdata)) {
         $request = json_decode($postdata);
         $userName = $request->username;
         $userPass = $request->password;
     }
    if (($userName == '') || ($userPass == '')) {
        $this->response(array('message' => 'Network Error! Try Again!!!'), 200);
    }else{
    $this->response(array('message' => 'Success'), 200);
  }
}
```

In Codeigniter we can use

```
$postdata = $this->input->raw_input_stream;
```

Don't know whether this is the best answer, but i am going with it now, would be good if someone can correct it if there is an better solution.

Comment: Please also try it like this: $this->input->input_stream('username'); or $postdata = $this->input->raw_input_stream; and then $username = $postdata['username'];

Comment: @Vladimir tried both but didnt work

  $userName = $this->input->input_stream('username');
  $userPass = $this->input->input_stream('password');
  $postdata = $this->input->raw_input_stream; 
  $username = $postdata['username']; 
  $userPass = $postdata['password'];