# Angular + PHP: Simplest way to POST an object?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I'm studying `php` and `angular`. Currently exploring the possibilities to send data to server side using `$http` service. This is what I came up with and it seem to work, but it doesn't look elegant.

Angular code:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'server.php',
    data: "newUser=" + JSON.stringify(user),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    } // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
})
.success(function (respose) {
    var x = JSON.parse(respose);
    console.log(JSON.parse(x));
}).error(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("some kind of error");
});
```

This is my `php` code to receive the data and return it:

```
if (isset($_POST["newUser"])) {
    $newUser = $_POST["newUser"];
    echo json_encode($newUser);
}
```

1. Why do I have to specify the name of the `json` I'm passing? I mean the `newUser` prefix under the `data` of the request.
2. Secondly, why do I have to `json.parse` twice the response in order to convert it back to a JS Object?
3. Why to I have to specify the headers in order to pass a simple JSON string?

Comment: Simply to serialize the data

Comment: If you send back json data add the appropriate headers `header('Content-Type: application/json');` this can help other's library to automatically convert it to json

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php (then you don't have to serialize the data) you could just send json

Comment: see here for the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15485690/2401804. just put a raw object as the `data` argument in your post request in the angular code. KISS = Keep It Simple Stupid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTTP post to PHP and undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. Why do I have to specify the name of the json I'm passing? I mean the newUser prefix under the data of the request.
>
> Q3. Why to I have to specify the headers in order to pass a simple JSON string?

In PHP, you have  global arrays like `$_POST` & `$_GET` to receive the data extracted from the request that are on the form of `key=value`.
 And `$_POST`  is filled when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as the HTTP Content-Type.

So in order to use these global arrays, you have to full-fill these two conditions

Okay the alternative way is to use `php://input` stream to directly read the raw input, so you can send the json string directly.

```
file_get_contents(“php://input”);
```