# Angular JSON post only sending one item of json array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, post

I wrote an angular quiz and I'm trying to send the quiz results to the database for processing. My $http call is as follows:

```
  function saveQuiz() {
      quizObj.isSaving = true;
      var data = {
          id: quiz_id,
          action: 'quiz_data',
          part: 'save_quiz',
          score: quizObj.score,
          passed: quizObj.passed,
          completed: quizObj.completed,
          percentage: quizObj.perc,
          time_spent: $filter('formatTimer')(quizObj.counter),
          questions: quizObj.quiz.questions
      };
      console.log(data);
      $http({
              url: quizapp.ajax_url,
              method: "POST",
              params: data
          })
          .then(function(response) {
                  console.log(response.data);

                  quizObj.isSaving = false;

              },
              function(response) { // optional
                  // failed
                  console.log(response);
              });
  }
```

Notice I am passing an array of json questions as quizObj.quiz.questions.
The problem on the server side is that $_POST['questions'] evaluates to the last item of the quizObj.quiz.questions json object instead of the full list.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I think it may be because you're using `params` with `method: "POST"`. try saying `data: data` instead of params on your `$http` config object and see if that works for you.

Comment: data:data worked out perfectly. Thanks mhodges I was pulling hairs

Comment: Oh my gosh, man you have no idea how many times I have done the same thing! Haha glad that worked for you! I will post an answer for future visitors

Comment: data:data worked out perfectly in sending the questions as array. I can see it in the console logs, however I am unable to access the variables on serverside using $_POST or $_REQUEST

Comment: [See this question & answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined) and let me know if those work for you

Answer (score 0):

When using the `$http` service through Angular, `data` goes with `method: "POST"` and `params` goes with `method: "GET"`

Change the properties on your config object you are passing to the `$http` service like so:

```
$http({
    url: quizapp.ajax_url,
    method: "POST",
    data: data // <-- data here, not params since using POST
}).then(function () { /*...*/ }));
```

Comment: my $_POST and $_REQUEST variables on serverside are returning null

Comment: @TommyAdeniyi [See this question & answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined) and let me know if those work for you

Comment: Adding this snippet to the top of my serverside file did the trick:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST))
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

Comment: @TommyAdeniyi Sweet, glad you got it up and working!