# Why is my $_POST empty but file_get_contents('php://input') is not?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, post

When I `POST` data to my server using a regular old form submit I can pull that data from the `$_POST` variable, but when `POST`ing JSON data via AJAX I need to access it via `file_get_contents('php://input')`. Why is that? In both cases I am using the `POST` method, are there some explicit headers I should be setting on my AJAX call? I have only ever come up against this problem on the current development server and have never had to use `file_get_contents('php://input')` before. Is there a server setting somewhere? Can I change this behaviour with a .htaccess?

Comment: There may be some useful info for you here, even if you aren't using angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined

Comment: you can tweak some headers to make it populate $_POST, but  cant remember which ones. (sorry not very helpfull)

Comment: Perhaps the content type for the POST request was something other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`. May be it was `application/json`. PHP will not populate `$_POST` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I have been able to find out, this has something to do with the way the data is received by the server - PHP can't natively parse JSON. Sending plain old JSON objects from Javascript to PHP will result in PHP not knowing what to do with the datatype, and thus it won't be able to prepopulate the appropriate global variables.

In order to get around it I added a check to my ajax wrapper function that intercepts the JSON, encodes is as a `FormData` object and shoots that off to the server instead.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the top of your .php file:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

so that the contents will be property decoded and available. After that, you can access individual keys as usual.

Comment: I've been doing that but I want to know _why_. And why I haven't had to do it before.

Comment: @AbrahamBrookes My understanding is that it is simply because the payload is JSON and to properly be able to create the POST array, the JSON must be decoded.