# Retreive Html form value in a PHP script using an Angular Service

Tags: php, angular, angular-services

I have an Angular 5 App with a contact form and I want to be able to retreive data from this form via a service in my PHP Script.

Here is my html

```
contact.html

<div class="">
   <input [(ngModel)]= "subjet" name="subjet" type="text">
   <label for="">subject</label>
</div>
```

When I click on my from button I call a function `sendmail(subject)` in the same component.

```
contact.component.ts

export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private  sendMailService:SendMailService) { }

    sendmail(subjet):void{
         this.sendMailService.performGetEx().subscribe(  (v => 
         console.log('value: ', v)),
         (e => console.log('error: ', e)),
         (() => console.log('the sequence completed! :' ,subjet)));
    }
```

And finally my service :

```
Injectable()
export class SendMailService {

  private url = 'assets/php/sendmail.php'

 constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
   performGetEx():Observable<any>{
     return this.http.get<any>(this.url,
     {
         responseType: 'text' as 'json'
     });
}
```

This service is the one that use the PHP Script but I can't find a way to retreive my `subject` value in my PHP Script.

When I do something like that `$sujet = $_POST['sujet'];`it doesn't work. It could have worked if my script was in the same folder as my `contact component` but it's not the case.

Do you know how I can do It ?

**UPDATE 1 :**

This link could be helpful, it might be the solution for people that have this issue : [Angular HTTP post to PHP and undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined)

Im my case when I do the following :

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$subject = $request->subject;
```

I have an error because my `$postdata` variable is empty ! Still don't know why

**UPDATE 2 :**

Like @Simos said I checked and I didn't see the data sent from Angular in my network.

So I changed my `SendmailService class` method from `get` to `post`.

```
Injectable()
export class SendMailService {

  private url = 'assets/php/sendmail.php'

 constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
   performGetEx():Observable<any>{
     return this.http.post<any>(this.url,
     {
         responseType: 'text' as 'json'
     });
}
```

I get an other error `HttpErrorResponse SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse`.

I already had this error before and had to add the `reponseType: 'text' as 'json'` in order to avoid it...And now it don't work with the `post` method....

Comment: Angular sends $_POST info in a way that's not available via the `$_POST` superglobal.  Have you checked out this question / answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined

Comment: @cale_b Thanks for your answer, Indeed I think it's a good track !
 Imo the answer to my problem is given by the top response, the only probleme is that when I try this `$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");`, my variable is empty....Another problem then

Comment: If you see the network, do you see the data sent from Angular ?

Comment: Indeed I don't see the data....I don't get it...The only thing to do is to have the `method="post"` in my form no ?