# TypeError: Cannot read property 'param' of undefined in angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, json

```js
$scope.productDetails = {};
$scope.getProductDetailById = function(arg) {

  var data = $.param({
    id: arg
  });

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://' + $scope.url + '/scripts/viewProductById.php',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;'
    },
    data: data
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.productDetails = response.data;
    $location.path('/single_product');
  },
  function(response) {
    //alert('wrong');
  })
}
```

Getting this error in console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'param' of undefined

Here is my Backend code which is written in PHP and I have checked with postman and data is fetching in json:

```
session_start();
require 'db.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id='$id'";
$qur = $connection->query($sql);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qur);
$msg[] = array("id" => $r['id'],"name" => $r['name'],"category" => $r['category'],"material" => $r['material'],
"pattern" => $r['pattern'],"occasion" => $r['occasion'],"length" => $r['length'],"width" => $r['width'],
"wash_care" => $r['wash_care'],"color" => $r['color'],"stock" => $r['stock'],"new_price" => $r['new_price'],
"old_price" => $r['old_price'],"delivery_in" => $r['delivery_in'],"image_one" => $r['image_one'],
"image_two" => $r['image_two'],"image_three" => $r['image_three'],"image_four" => $r['image_four'],
"image_five" => $r['image_five'],"description" => $r['description'],"date" => $r['date']);

$json = $msg;

header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
@mysqli_close($connection);
```

After changing :

```
var data = {
id: arg
  };
```

Getting Empty data

[image]

Comment: `param` is a property of `$`, which is undefined. What is `$`? jQuery? Do you have a script for it?

Comment: No, Just I have used jquery library and angular.min.js

Comment: I am calling lot of function but only this function I am getting like this.

Comment: can you not just call `$http.post('http://'+ $scope.url +'/scripts/viewProductById.php', { id:arg })` ?

Comment: But same code working in my admin dashboard project

Comment: How do you include jquery?

Comment: I have used external file

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use it like this.

```
var data = $.param({
    id: arg
});
```

The data variable can just be an [Object Literal](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/object-literal/) like so.

```
var data = {
    id: arg
};
```

Comment: Status is 200 but data is empty

Comment: @Chit that depends on your backend. e.g. with PHP, double check if you are using `echo json_encode(...)`

Comment: Uploaded please check it

Comment: Still need help

Comment: @Chit Check if you get the data in $_POST['id']

Comment: I think my back end is correct because I am getting data in postman rest client.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined

Comment: still same problem

Comment: @Chit You did change 'Content-Type': 'application/json', right?