# angular js keep showing me undefined value when i use http post

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-http

i'm trying to pass a value to a php file using Post when i do that and i want to read the value from php as json it keeps telling me it's undefined. I don't know where is the mistake

this is my angular.js code

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("mainController",['$scope','$http','$interval', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
  var url = "user_check.php";

  $scope.lost = "well doe";
  var val = "come on ";
  $interval(function(){
  $http.post(url,{val:val})
    .success(function(data) {
      console.log(data.name);
    })  
    .error(function(data) {

    });

  },0.4)
}]);
```

and this is my php file

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['val '])){
$data['name']="rose";

    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Comment: What version of AngularJS? The `.success` and `.error` methods have been deprecated and removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Docs:

> $_POST
>
> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.
>
> — [PHP Manual - Reserved variable - $_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

The AngularJS framework does POST request with `application/json` as the HTTP Content-Type.

Instead use:<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15485690/5535245)</sup>

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

For more information, see

- [PHP Manual - Supported wrappers and protocols - php://](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)
- [PHP Manual - Function Reference - file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
- [PHP Manual - Function Reference - json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)