# Passing data from Angularjs to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am really new to Angular. I am trying to pass a variable to php but the response is " Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" and null for the array.

js file:

```
var myData = {
            fruit1: 'apple',
            fruit2: 'banana'
        };


$http({
    url: "test.php",
        method: "POST",
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: myData
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
});
```

php file:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$data = $request->myData;

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Check the network tab in the Developer Console to see if the request sent is actually a POST request and not an OPTIONS request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTTP post to PHP and undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.success` and `.error` methods [have been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35331339/5535245) from the AngularJS framework. Instead, use the `.then` and `.catch` methods:

```
var myData = {
    fruit1: 'apple',
    fruit2: 'banana'
};

$http({
    url: "test.php",
    method: "POST",
    ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶:̶ ̶{̶ ̶'̶C̶o̶n̶t̶e̶n̶t̶-̶T̶y̶p̶e̶'̶:̶ ̶'̶a̶p̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶/̶j̶s̶o̶n̶'̶ ̶}̶,̶
    data: myData
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
    return response.data;
}).catch(function(err) {
    $scope.status = err.status;
    throw err;
});
```

The $http service automatically JSON encodes data and automatically sets the content type to `application/json`.

In this case, the code does not use the promise returned by the `.then` and `.catch` methods. If the promise is used, it is important to have `return` and `throw` statements in the success and rejection handlers.

### php file:

```
$postJSON = file_get_contents("php://input");
$dataArr = json_decode($postJSON, TRUE);

var_dump($dataArr);
```

The JSON encoded data is found in the body of the POST request. The name of the variable is not sent, only the contents.

The second argument of the `json_decode` function, specifies that objects be converted to associative arrays.

Keep in mind that these POST requests are subject to [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). The XHR request must be made from a website page that has the same origin as the page receiving the POST request.