# passing array javascript to controller codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i having problem with passing array from view to controller. Here's the case:

VIEW

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
function displayDet(kode,rowNo,rows){
    var jsarr = new Array();
    jsarr = {'kode': kode,'rowno':rowNo,'rows':rows};
    //alert(jsarr['kode']+jsarr['rowno']+jsarr['rows']);
    window.location.href='http://localhost/ci_hiandgirls/index.php/sales/sales/form_so_arr/'+jsarr;  
}
</script>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function form_so_arr( $params = array() ){
    foreach($params as $val){
        $view['detRows'] = $val['rows'];
        $view['kode'] = $val['kode'];
        $view['rowNo'] = $val['rowNo'];
    }       
    $this->load->view('sales/form',$view);
}
```

Is this right ? it's show error message "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". I just want to catch array from javascript then send back the values to VIEW. kindly please help me.

Comment: `var jsarr = new Array();
     jsarr = {'kode': kode,'rowno':rowNo,'rows':rows};`

This is not array, this is object. Simply do

`var jsarr = {'kode': kode,'rowno':rowNo,'rows':rows};`

Comment: i've tried it, still same error

Comment: How do you get the json object from your url in the controller? I think you would have to json_decode it before you can loop through it with a foreach in php.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like bad practice.  But if you want to do it like this pass the parameters as different url segments like

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function displayDet(kode,rowNo,rows){
window.location.href='http://localhost/ci_hiandgirls/index.php/sales/sales/form_so_arr/'+kode+'/'+rowNo+'/'+rows;  
}
</script>
```

Also you shouldn't be hard coding your base URL, you want to do this dynamically because what happens if you move your site and the base URL changes.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice to send the array in url CI provides the `uri segment` to pass and get parameters from the url you can do it in this way also

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function displayDet(kode,rowNo,rows){
window.location.href='http://localhost/ci_hiandgirls/index.php/sales/sales/form_so_arr/'+kode+'/'+rowNo+'/'+rows;  
}
</script>
```

Now in your controller you can get these params as

```
public function form_so_arr(){
        $view['detRows'] = $this->uri->segment(6);
        $view['kode'] = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $view['rowNo'] = $this->uri->segment(5);

    $this->load->view('sales/form',$view);
}
```

You should read the [Uri Segment Working](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

Here is a little overview of uri segment that how it works

```
http://example.com/index.php/news/local/metro/crime_is_up
The segment numbers would be this:

uri segment (1) =>news
uri segment (2) =>local
uri segment (3) =>metro
uri segment (4) =>crime_is_up
```

Hope it makes sense

Comment: thanks for answer. But i mean if one of segment is array how to catch it in controller function ? I tried to sent array from View to Controller. Then i set "function form_so_arr($params = array())" Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You <strike>cannot</strike> shouldn't pass an array like that.  You should be using GET/POST, not the URI segments for this.

NOTE: You might need to edit the CodeIgniter config file to enable GET.

```
public function form_so_arr(){
    $params = $this->input->get('params');
    foreach($params as $val){
        $view['detRows'] = $val['rows'];
        $view['kode'] = $val['kode'];
        $view['rowNo'] = $val['rowNo'];
    }       
    $this->load->view('sales/form',$view);
}
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
// From http://stackoverflow.com/a/1714899
function serialize(obj, prefix) {
    var str = [];
    for(var p in obj) {
        var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
        str.push(typeof v == "object" ? 
            serialize(v, k) :
            encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
    }
    return str.join("&");
}

function displayDet(kode,rowNo,rows){
    var jsarr = {'kode': kode,'rowno':rowNo,'rows':rows};
    window.location.href='http://localhost/ci_hiandgirls/index.php/sales/sales/form_so_arr?'+serialize(jsarr,'params');
}
```

---

If you can't use the above method, you can still pass the array in the URI segment, just as a JSON string.

```
function displayDet(kode,rowNo,rows){
    var jsarr = {'kode': kode,'rowno':rowNo,'rows':rows};
    window.location.href='http://localhost/ci_hiandgirls/index.php/sales/sales/form_so_arr/'+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(jsarr));
}
```

Then in PHP:

```
public function form_so_arr($params='[]'){
    $params = json_decode(urldecode($params), TRUE);
    foreach($params as $val){
        $view['detRows'] = $val['rows'];
        $view['kode'] = $val['kode'];
        $view['rowNo'] = $val['rowNo'];
    }       
    $this->load->view('sales/form',$view);
}
```