# How to write a small helper function for Ajax Post requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax

such that an object literal contains the parameters you want to send and the result is a string you can send as data.

Here is my first try:

```
function makeData(obj) {
    var data_send = '';
    _.each(obj, function (val, key) {
        data_send += encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(val) + '&';
    });
    data_send.slice(1,-1);
    return data_send;
}
```

Is this the correct form for ajax post data?

Comment: What if val is an array?

Comment: obj is assumed to be well formed - just key value pairs.

Comment: An array is a valid "value" in an object - and it can be passed as a valid query string parameters using [] like items[]=firstitem&items[]=seconditem

Comment: Question has already been answered (quite well, too)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: ...well I don't need to support that just yet, I want to make sure the simple case works first, particularly my use of `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: wow...that's not too efficient...pushing to an array just so you can create a string later ... my way is a bit more efficient.

Comment: Creating one tiny JS array that exists in memory for the duration of a function execution is a non-issue. Don't fool yourself into thinking that that somehow matters.