# encodeURI Being overridden in safari

Tags: javascript, video.js, encodeuricomponent

### Overview

So I've written a Video.js plugin that reports back to google analytics and our custom reporting.

Each JSONP request we send back to our page is encoded using encodeURIComponent using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object).  The first few fire off correctly.  It then begins to error with `TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating 'encodeURIComponent(p)')`. This only happens in Safari. (I'm on safari 7.0.1 on OSX Mavericks)

I've even tried doing the whole url string using `encodeURI` but the samething happens to that function as well.

I've created a [JS FIDDLE][2] to demonstrate the problem.  I've been unsuccessful at re-creating it with just some sample code so i've included all the relevant files in the external resources.  If it does not do it, re-run the page its happening for me about 85% of the time.

### Stepping through the functions

I first add the events to track

```
this.on('play',onPlay);
this.on('pause',onPause);
```

When an event fires it is caught by these functions

```
function onPlay( e ) {
    videoData = getVideoData();
    doTracking({
        'category': videoData.cid,
        'action': videoData.vid,
        'label': 'Play',
        'value': null
    });
}

function onPause( e ) {
    videoData = getVideoData();
    doTracking({
        'category': videoData.cid,
        'action': videoData.vid,
        'label': 'Pause',
        'value': getTime()
    });
}
```

Which gets video data from

```
function getVideoData() {
    var src = videojsRef.player().currentSrc();
    var srcSplit = src.split('/');

    var filename = srcSplit[srcSplit.length-1];
    var filenameSplit = filename.split('.');

    var cid = filenameSplit[0];
    var vid = filenameSplit[1];
    var type = filenameSplit[2];

    var returnObj = {
        'cid': cid,
        'vid': vid,
        'filename': filename
    };

    return returnObj;
}
```

And then calls "doTracking" which is just a helper function that calls both tracking functions.

```
function doTracking( opt ) {

    if ( gaType && bvReady ) { // Are both tracking types initialized
        // Send to google
        googleTrack( opt );

        // Send to BetterVideo
        bvTrack( opt );
    } else {
        queue.push( opt );
    }
}
```

Which calls bvTrack( opt )

```
function bvTrack( opt ) {
    var args = {
        pid: playerid,
        cid: opt.category,
        vcd: opt.action,
        a: opt.label,
        callback: '{callback}'          
    };

    if ( opt.value !== null ) {
        args.val = opt.value;
    }

    // Heres where the trouble starts
    new videojs.JSONP('http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/?'+serializeToQuery(args), function( response ) {
        console.log('[BV Reporting] Tracking Response: ', arguments );
    })
}
```

The data gets serialized in here

```
function serializeToQuery( obj ) {
    var str = [];
    console.log( "serializeToQuery", obj );
    for(var p in obj) {

        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(p) ) {
            console.log( '    property', p, obj[p]);
            console.log( '        encodeURIComponent', typeof encodeURIComponent == 'function' ? 'function' : encodeURIComponent );
            console.log( '        encoded property', encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p])); 
        }
    }   
    return str.join("&");
}
```

and then passed to the [d3.js inspired JSONP](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/jsonp/jsonp.js) (which i believe i found here on SO

```
videojs.JSONP = function (url, callback) {
    var docHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    function rand() {
        var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        c = '', i = -1;
        while (++i < 15) c += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 52));
        return c;
    }

    function create(url) {
        var e = url.match(/callback=jsonp.(\w+)/),
        c = e ? e[1] : rand();
        videojs.JSONP[c] = function(data) {
            callback(data);
            delete videojs.JSONP[c];
            docHead.removeChild(script);
        };
        return 'videojs.JSONP.' + c;
    }

    var cb = create(url),
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = url.replace(/(\{|%7B)callback(\}|%7D)/, cb);
        docHead.appendChild(script)
};
```

### Output

```
serializeToQuery Object { 
                            a: "Pause"
                            callback: "{callback}"
                            cid: "oceans"
                            pid: "885FA551-A873-4BB9-891A-ABC08CD47D36"
                            val: 6
                            vcd: "mp4"
                        }
    property pid 885FA551-A873-4BB9-891A-ABC08CD47D36
        encodeURIComponent function
        encoded property pid=885FA551-A873-4BB9-891A-ABC08CD47D36
    property cid oceans
        encodeURIComponent function
        encoded property cid=oceans
    property vcd mp4
        encodeURIComponent function
        encoded property vcd=mp4
    property a Pause
        encodeURIComponent function
        encoded property a=Pause
    property callback {callback}
        encodeURIComponent function
        encoded property callback=%7Bcallback%7D
    property val 6
        encodeURIComponent function
        encoded property val=6
```

But after 2 or 3 JSONP calls, it outputs this:

```
serializeToQuery Object {
                            a: "Play"
                            callback: "{callback}"
                            cid: "oceans"
                            pid: "885FA551-A873-4BB9-891A-ABC08CD47D36"
                            vcd: "mp4"
                        }

    property pid 885FA551-A873-4BB9-891A-ABC08CD47D36 
        encodeURIComponent  Object {
                                        cid: "oceans"
                                        filename: "oceans.mp4"
                                        vid: "mp4"
                                    }

[Error] TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating 'encodeURIComponent(p)')
    serializeToQuery (videojs.bvReporting.js, line 531)
    bvTrack (videojs.bvReporting.js, line 481)
    doTracking (videojs.bvReporting.js, line 329)
    onPlay (videojs.bvReporting.js, line 113)
    ret (video.dev.js, line 769)
    dispatcher (video.dev.js, line 295)
    trigger (video.dev.js, line 529)
    trigger (video.dev.js, line 1868)
    eventHandler (video.dev.js, line 5376)
    ret (video.dev.js, line 769)
    dispatcher (video.dev.js, line 295)
```

As you can see `encodeURIComponent` is now the last object it was called with.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `vjs.Core.extend` ever called with an object that includes `encodeURIComponent` as a key and `window` as the object to extend?

Comment: Accourding to your logging, `encodeURIComponent` function has been replaced by an `Object { cid: "oceans" ... }`. Are you're not overriding `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: @MikeSamuel I can't find anything that would be doing that.  I've removed the encodeURIComponent call in the `serializeToQuery` function and added `encodeURI` to the JSONP call and that call does the same thing.

Comment: @jerone I'm not intentionally overriding it and its working properly in other browsers including other webkit browsers.

Comment: Updated the question to show flow of the reporting.

Comment: Interesting development.  I added the same console.log statement throughout the entire flow (except in `getVideoData`) and noticed that `encodeURIComponent` was being overwritten inside of "onPlay" the only thing in there was the `getVideoData` so I threw the console.log statement in there as well.  This completely fixed the problem.  Just adding the `console.log( 'getVideoData        encodeURIComponent', typeof encodeURIComponent == 'function' ? 'function' : encodeURIComponent );` fixed it and i can no longer replicate the issue... now to find out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each of the tracking event listeners there is / was `videoData = getVideoData()`  once I added `var` to `videoData` the issue ceased.  Does anyone see why that may be cause?  I understand it was being set to a global variable but how does encodeURIComponent get set to the object?