# How to pass '&' in queryString value

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am creating queryString from Javacript like below

```
serialize = function(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for(var p in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    }
  return str.join("&");
}
```

[Js solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714899/1521447)

I am passing a parameter which contains '&' (ampersand) character like below:

```
activityCategory=Cruises, Sailing & Water Tours
```

url encoded value:

```
activityCategory=Cruises%2C%20Sailing%20%26%20Water%20Tours
```

But

```
Request.QueryString["activityCategory"]
```

is returning `Cruises, Sailing` only.
How can I get full value of `activityCategory`

Comment: The approach you have is correct. Something must be breaking it between you encoding it and it reaching the Request object on the server.

Comment: How exactly are you checking the value on the server?

Comment: I am checking through debugging `ActivityCategory = SecurityManager.Encoder.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["activityCategory"] ?? Request.Form["activityCategory"])`

Comment: If it is interpreting it incorrectly, `Request.QueryString.Keys` should contain " Water Tours". Can you check that?

Comment: There is no " Water Tours" key. But I can see null after "ActivityCategory" and than other keys

Comment: Please check the _actual_ value of `Request.QueryString["activityCategory"]` and not the result you get after passing it through `SecurityManager.Encoder.HtmlEncode()` (whatever that is). There could very well be a bug in that HtmlEncode() method.

Comment: I checked again and I can see wrong value is returning from `Request.QueryString["activityCategory"]`.