# How to encode a JavaScript array as PHP-compatible "array arguments" in a query string?

Tags: javascript, php, string, http

I have a jQuery array and I want to use it in an AJAX call with my PHP script, can anyone help me do this?

```
var things = {
  "foo": ["bar", "baz"],
  "bar": 1234
};

var output = "?foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz&bar=1234";
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Here's your answer :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 5):

`$.param(myobj, true)`

From the manual:

> As of jQuery 1.4, the $.param() method serializes deep objects recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks such as PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can disable this functionality globally by setting jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;.
>
> As of jQuery 1.8, the $.param() method no longer uses jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional as its default setting and will default to false. For best compatibility across versions, call $.param() with an explicit value for the second argument and do not use defaults.

Answer (score 2):

`$.param(things, true)`

The above will help you here. The second parameter allows for arrays. Make sure you have [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) installed