# Encoding and decoding an object to and from URL

Tags: javascript, url, encoding

I am trying to encode and decode an object from a url. The structure of the object looks like so

```
 myObj =
 {"obj1": {"sub1" : 1, "sub2", "2"},
  "obj2": {"sub1" : 1, "sub2", "2"},
  "obj3": {"sub1" : 1, "sub2", "2"} }
```

And So what I'm trying to do is encode it and decode it from the url - for reference this is for saving a "state". So it encode it, I have

```
 encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
```

And to decode I have :

```
JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(searchString));
```

Then using Angualrs,

```
 $location.search();
```

to set and pull the url.

This was working fine until I changed the values inside the object to objects them selves, the URL just says "object", and I can't pull any data from it. Could use some help. The basic Idea is - i just want to be able to save and pull this object from the url. Thanks!

Update :

it seems when I encode a new object I get a result like this

```
   {{"obj1":{"sub1":true}}: true}
```

so it's acting very oddly with the object

Edit:

Upon further research it appears what I'm looking for is something like jquery's param (and deparam), but in just javascript?

Comment: What's wrong with using jQuery if it does the job?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1714899/379855

Comment: @tadman nothing wrong with jquery! I just don't use it now so it would be nice to not bring it in for 1 thing.

Comment: @Donal awesome thanks for linking, i see the serialize funciton, is there a de-serialize too?

Comment: try JSON.parse(string);