# Angular.js: get post-data in $_POST variable

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm quite new to angular.js. Now I try to post some data to a PHP-Script.

**angular.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('sendData', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.post("script.php", {'value': 'one'} )
    .success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

So I would get the data in `$data->value`.

Is it possible to modify the script (without using $.param of JQuery), so I could access the post-data with `$_POST['value']` - as I would normally do that in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` is for using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

So, in order to use `x-www-form-urlencoded` (and `$_POST`), you **must** serialize your data properly whether you are using the `$.param` function or another serialize method.

This is how we do it, although like I said, you can use a different function than `$.param` if you need to.

```
$http({
  method: "post",
  url: url,
  data: $.param(data),
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```

Here is a vanilla js method of serialization:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714899/580487