# Codeigniter + Angular issue with $http.post(). Codeigniter not receive data

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have strange Codeigniter - Angular issue.
My idea was to set up controller to work like this:

- index is simple Angular page, just 1 app and 1 controller
- get is get data from database
- set is save data which are sent using $http.post

Problem is that `$http.post()` send proper data, I see it in Firebug,
but CI doesn't catch that.

I change header parameters, tried to catch with `file_get_contents("php://input")` and `$this->input->post`, but always was `Null`.

Any idea?

I tried this:

```
$http(   
{
method: 'POST',
url: url,
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
transformRequest: function (obj) {
var str = [];
for (var p in obj)
str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
return str.join("&");
},

data: data
});
```

With and without headers and transformData changes... and nothing.

#### UPDATE

I tried to send same data to raw php script, and it's worked. so, somehow - Codeigniter blocking this.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

this is a common problem, lets begin:
add [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) script to your document
and in your app Module, add this code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"]).
config(["$httpProvider",function($httpProvider) 
{
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function($q) {
    return {
            request: function(config) {
                if (config.data && typeof config.data === 'object') {
                    // Check https://gist.github.com/brunoscopelliti/7492579 
                    // for a possible way to implement the serialize function.
                    config.data = serialize(config.data);
                }
                return config || $q.when(config);
            }
        };
    }]);

    var serialize = function(obj, prefix) {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj) {
            var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
            str.push(typeof v == "object" ? serialize(v, k) : encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
        }
        return str.join("&");
    }

}]).
run(function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;";

});
```

now on your postService (or wherever you are using $http)

```
var postData = function(method,data) {
   return $http.post("controller.php?/"+method,{data:data})
   .then(function(response) {                
        return response.data;                    
    }, 
    function(response) {        
      //handle error
    }); 
 }

//use
postData("userLogin",{username:"username",password:"password"}).then(function(response){

});
```

and now codeIgniter will get the input->post("data") (it's always data);

Comment: Tried that and not working:
data[name] Delivery Name
data[notes] 
data[ranges][0][from] 0
data[ranges][0][to] 0
data[showRanges] false
data[url] http://
data[weight_from] 0
data[weight_to] 0
in POST, but on CI side Null

Comment: well this need to see what you are doing, can you edit your post and show what you are doing in CI?

Comment: file_get_contents("php://input")
also tried $this->input->post();

and when I try print_r() it returns Null (first) or Array() for second.

Comment: try $this->input->post("data"); and print_r($_POST)

Comment: has this question been answered yet or not? I am working on the same situation right now.

Comment: Angular 1.5+ solved it automatically using

`$http({
               method:"POST",
               url : "api/"+apiMethod,
               headers: {
                    'Content-Type': "application/json"
                },
                data : data
           })`