# Posting JSON array to server using angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, post

I have been trying to post JSON array to the server using angularjs. but its not reading the array part.I am able to send the non array part which are username,password and status with the following code

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:57302/api/Messages',
    data: {
        "Username": "SampleUsername",
        "Password": "SamplePassword",
        "Messages": [{
            "From": "Harsh",
            "to": "Rahul",
            "Body": "Hi there",
        }, {
            "From": "Harsh",
            "to": "Rahul",
            "Body": "How are you",
        }, {
            "From": "Rahul",
            "to": "Harsh",
            "Body": "I am Good",
        }],
        "Status": "SampleStatus",
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    }
})
```

What changes are required in order to send the array part as well?

Comment: why not use `Content-Type: application/json` without any transformations?

Comment: I just modified that..it says XMLhttpRequest Invalid 400

Comment: Seems like your server is not set up to accept `application/json` properly.

Comment: But it works when using jquery and I was also able to post json objects but not arrays

Comment: Do you use jQuery? It has useful method `$.param(data)` which acts as your transformRequest but more properly.

Comment: I really want to do it using pure angular since jquery is conflicting with ionic   framework (the technology I am using for building my front end)

Comment: You can use workarond: `angular.toJson(data)` and `json_decode(data)` (php) on server

Comment: But the most correct way is to use `application/json`.

Comment: Or write your `transformRequest` function more properly (see how it's done in jQuery.param method). Now your function goes only one level deep within data structure.

Comment: do I have to do somthing like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object)?

Comment: here, you do not post JSON but an url-form-encoded, transforming the JSON in a URLEncoded string. Why not sending JSON directly in the POST ? URLEncoding is usually used for GET request where you serialize data to be in the HTTP URL request. For post you can simply post json with correct content-type, and on server side, you read JSON data in the body of the request.

Comment: @osallou if I remove transformRequest and set Content-Type as application/json it gives me http status code 400 - XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:57302/api/Messages

Comment: but on server-side, do you read from the body of the message?

Comment: Whenn I send just a json object, I am able to recieve it on the server side but not json array